# Slices of triangular alphabets

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Given an input number `n` from `1` to `26` (or `0` to `25`), output the alphabet reading left-to-right up to and including that corresponding letter, with `a=1, b=2, c=3, ...`. The twist is the letters must also be repeated vertically corresponding to their position in the alphabet. Odd numbers (when `1`-indexed) should be balanced across the horizontal line, while even numbers should alternate between favoring the top or bottom (you can choose which direction to go first). If you're 0-indexing, then swap odd/even in the previous sentence.

Worded another way -- if the alphabetical value of a letter `?` is `#`, then there should be `#` copies of that letter in the output, all of them in the `#`th column. These letters should be evenly balanced above and below the horizontal line that has the `a`. If the letters cannot be balanced evenly, then alternate having the "extra" letter above and below that line.

Here are the first six outputs (`n = 1,2,3,4,5,6`, 1-indexed, choosing to alternate to the bottom first), separated by newlines, so you can see the pattern. Comments explaining the pattern start with `#`.

```
a         # On a line by itself

ab
 b        # The "extra" letter is below the horizontal

  c
abc       # The 'c' splits evenly
 bc

   d      # Because the 'b' was below, the extra 'd' must be above
  cd
abcd
 bcd


   de
  cde
abcde     # The 'e' balances
 bcde
    e

   def
  cdef
abcdef
 bcdef
    ef
     f    # Since the 'd' was above, the extra 'f' must be below
```

(skip a few to `n=26`)

```
                       xyz
                      wxyz
                   tuvwxyz
                  stuvwxyz
               pqrstuvwxyz
              opqrstuvwxyz
           lmnopqrstuvwxyz
          klmnopqrstuvwxyz
       hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
      ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
   defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
  cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
     fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
        ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
         jklmnopqrstuvwxyz
            mnopqrstuvwxyz
             nopqrstuvwxyz
                qrstuvwxyz
                 rstuvwxyz
                    uvwxyz
                     vwxyz
                        yz
                         z
```

#### Rules

- You can choose to output in uppercase or lowercase, but it must be consistent.
- The output cannot have extraneous whitespace, except for an optional trailing newline.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- The input number can be taken via [any suitable format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <del>20</del> 18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ḷ&2’×ḶỤØaḣ⁸¤ṫW€UGU
```

Port of my Python answer. [Try it online.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=JjLigJnDlwrhuLbDh8Oe4oCYw5hh4bijwrPCpOG5q1figqxVR1U&input=&args=MTk)

EDIT: Dennis saved two bytes by using `Ụ` (grade up) instead of `Þ` (sort by)!

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2, <del>101</del> 99 bytes

```
r=range(input())
for x in sorted(r,key=lambda x:x*-(x&2)):print bytearray([97+i,32][i<x]for i in r)
```

xsot saved two bytes by realizing `x*-(x&2)` suffices as a sorting key — the bottom half of the resulting image is unaffected due to `sorted` guaranteeing a stable sort.

Comment: Can you not drop a `-` to output the lines in reverse order, which I believe is allowable?

Comment: I think `x*-(x&2)` works.

Answer (score 6):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 26 bytes

A perfect score for a challenge about alphabet.

```
j_C.e<u_G/k2.[.|1Q*hkbdQ<G
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j_C.e%3Cu_G%2Fk2.%5B.%7C1Q%2ahkbdQ%3CG&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=5%0A26&debug=0)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 25 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
RØaxŒgz⁶W€;ṚL‘$¡¥/Ṛ⁸H¤¡j⁷
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UsOYYXjFkmd64oG2V-KCrDvhuZpM4oCYJMKhwqUv4bma4oG4SMKkwqFq4oG3&input=&args=MjY) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UsOYYXjFkmd64oG2V-KCrDvhuZpM4oCYJMKhwqUv4bma4oG4SMKkwqFq4oG3CsOH4oKsauKAnMK2wrY&input=&args=MSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNSwgNiwgMjY).

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>127</s> 126 bytes

```
n=>[...Array(n).keys()].sort((a,b)=>a*~-(a&2)-b*~-(b&2)).map(i=>` `.repeat(i)+`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.slice(i,n)).join`\n`
```

Uses @Lynn's sort trick. Writing out the whole alphabet was two bytes cheaper than calculating it. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @ETHproductions because I forgot to note that `\n` actually represents the literal newline character. (I don't like putting literal newlines in my answer when the line is so long.)

Comment: Save two bytes on the alphabet: ``btoa`...` `` where `...` is replaced with the result of ``atob`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzz` ``. (Also, you can replace `\n` with a literal newline.)

Comment: @ETHproductions I take it that would be using ISO encoding, rather than UTF?

Comment: Yes it would. Are we allowed to use ISO-8859-1 rather than UTF-8 in JS?

Comment: @ETHproductions Probably but I can't seem to get it to work, so I won't show it.