# Print an alphabet wave

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, alphabet

You are to print this exact text:

```
ABABABABABABABABABABABABAB
BCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBC
CDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCD
DEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDE
EFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEF
FGFGFGFGFGFGFGFGFGFGFGFGFG
GHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGH
HIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHI
IJIJIJIJIJIJIJIJIJIJIJIJIJ
JKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKJK
KLKLKLKLKLKLKLKLKLKLKLKLKL
LMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLM
MNMNMNMNMNMNMNMNMNMNMNMNMN
NONONONONONONONONONONONONO
OPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOP
PQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQ
QRQRQRQRQRQRQRQRQRQRQRQRQR
RSRSRSRSRSRSRSRSRSRSRSRSRS
STSTSTSTSTSTSTSTSTSTSTSTST
TUTUTUTUTUTUTUTUTUTUTUTUTU
UVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUV
VWVWVWVWVWVWVWVWVWVWVWVWVW
WXWXWXWXWXWXWXWXWXWXWXWXWX
XYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXY
YZYZYZYZYZYZYZYZYZYZYZYZYZ
ZAZAZAZAZAZAZAZAZAZAZAZAZA
```

## Specs

- You can print all lowercase instead of all uppercase. However, case must be consistent throughout the output.
- You may print one extra trailing linefeed.

## Scoring

Since this is an alphabet wave that fluctuates to a small extent, your code should also be small in terms of byte-count. In fact, the smallest code in terms of byte-count wins.

Comment: Seriously, *another* alphabet challenge?

Comment: @NathanMerrill As numerous as they are, I don't think they are worthy of downvotes. (I do not imply you downvoted, I am merely saying.)

Comment: As long as the patterns are sufficiently different, I don't think it matters if we use the alphabet, decimal digits, asterisks and underscore, etc.

Comment: Can I use function return?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien No, the same with the other alphabet challenges.

Comment: @Dennis regardless of the characters used, its these type of "pattern" challenges that are getting overused, IMO.  I don't think its offtopic, but I would enjoy some fresh air.

Comment: Merely generating the alphabet makes for overlapping code in Python for all these challenges.

Comment: It's clear there's no more demand for alphabet challenges - only 39 people answered in the first 15 hours...

Comment: These challenges instantly go HNQ and the result is a massive amount of votes for an otherwise meh challenge

Comment: @Insane If it is a meh challenge it would not have gone HNQ

Comment: @LeakyNun Lots of meh challenges go to HNQ. The HNQ algorithm favors answers. On our site, that doesn't work so well, because the number of answers to a challenge is proportional to the triviality of the challenge.

Comment: This might not be a Programming Puzzle, but it´s definitely Code Golf. Four answers with different approaches for some languages - I like the diversity.

Comment: Can I use a leading linebreak instead of a trailing one?

Answer (score 40):

## C, 60 bytes

```c
main(i){for(;i<703;)putchar(i++%27?65+(i/27+i%27%2)%26:10);}
```

Comment: This is genius.

Comment: Nice to see C in a code golf challenge.

Comment: @MichealJohnson "_see C_", I C what you did there. ;) And I agree with _Leaky Nun_. Sometimes I wonder how people come up with some of these ingenious answers.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen That was unintentional lol.

Answer (score 18):

## Brainfuck, 104 bytes

```
>+[+[<]>>+<+]><<+++++[>+++++>>++<<<-]>[-<+++++++++++++[->>.+.-<<]>>>.<+<]<----[>+<----]>++>>+++[-<.<.>>]
```

Comment: Practically the same size as Hello World. Impressive!

Comment: @phyrfox [Actually...](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world/68494#68494)

Answer (score 14):

### Convex, 10 bytes

```
U_(+]D*zN*
```

[Try it online!](http://convex.tryitonline.net/#code=VV8oK11EKnpOKg&input=)

```
U               Predefined Variable: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
 _(+            Push a copy with the 'A at the end.
    ]           Add both strings to an array.
     D*         Repeat array 13 times. D defaults to 13.
       z        Transpose.
        N*      Join by newlines. N defaults to "\n"
```

Answer (score 9):

### Pyth, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
jC*13.<BG1
```

[Try it here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jC%2a13.%3CBG1&debug=0)

```
        G   the alphabet
       B    bifurcate over
     .<  1  left shift by 1
  *13       repeat 13 times
 C          transpose
j           join on newlines
```

Answer (score 8):

## Ruby, <s>42</s> <s>39</s> <s>38</s> 37 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to @user81655
-1 byte thanks to @manatwork
-1 byte thanks to @NotthatCharles

```
?A.upto(?Z){|a|puts (a+a.next[0])*13}
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/CmOJ

Comment: Nowdays with Ruby 2.7 you can use _1 and you can go down to 36 bytes.
```?A.upto(?Z){puts (_1+_1.next[0])*13}```

Answer (score 8):

## Vim, <s>85</s> 83 bytes

```
:h<_<cr><cr><cr>YZZP:s/./\0\r/g<cr><c+v>ggy25Pqqlxj:let @a='xkPjj'<cr>25@akia<esc>25klq11@qh<ctrl+v>25jylpl<c+v>25jdGdd
```

I know this can be golfed more, but my head hurts so I gotta stop for now.

`<cr>` is the enter key, `<c+v>` is ctrl+v, and `<esc>` is the escape key. Those were all counted as one byte.

I recorded a gif of this, but it got screwed up. The video is fine though: http://recordit.co/ldLKvho9Gi

Answer (score 7):

## Cheddar, 48 bytes

```
print(65|>90).map(l->@"[l,l>89?65:l+1]*13).vfuse
```

Cheddar is good with strings :D

[Try it online!](http://cheddar.tryitonline.net/#code=cHJpbnQoNjV8PjkwKS5tYXAobC0-QCJbbCxsPjg5PzY1OmwrMV0qMTMpLnZmdXNl&input=)

### Explanation

```
print
  (65|>90)            // Range from 65 (A) to 90 (Z)
  .map(l->            // Map through range
    @"                // Convert following array of char codes to string
      [l,             // The character 
       l>89?65:l+1]   // See below for explanation
      *13             // Repeat 13 times
  ).vfuse             // Vertically fuse
```

What does `l>89?65:l+1` do? Well `89` is the char code for `Y`. Basically, `l>89` is checking if the letter is `Z`, that means we should be returning `A`. If `l>89` is false. I'll return `l+1`, the next char

Comment: I thought you can insert `@"` between them.

Comment: Doesn't this use a function return?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien yeah?

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89283/print-an-alphabet-wave/89286?noredirect=1#comment217722_89283

Comment: @ConorO'Brien oh, didn't see in challenge spec. will fix

Comment: @Downgoat it isn't in spec >_< just in comments

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, <s>60</s> 58 bytes

```
mapM putStrLn[[0..12]>>[a,b]|a:b:_<-scanr(:)"A"['A'..'Z']]
```

Starting with "A" `scanr(:)` builds the a list from the chars of `['A'..'Z']` from the right. (->  `["ABCDE...A", "BCDEF..A", ...,  "XYZA", "YZA", "ZA", "A"]`). `(a:b:_)` matches the first two chars of each sublists (with at least two chars) and makes 13 copies of it.

Comment: Considering some of the cheats used by other languages on a regular basis I consider it only fair to not include the actual printing. In this case you could replace it with "(++"\n")=<<" and save 2 bytes. Possibly more.

Comment: @MarLinn: No, I don't think so. Golfing languages are designed with implicit printing in mind and most other answers do have some sort of printing command. Btw, `unlines` is even shorter than `(++"\n")=<<`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
26ḶḂØAṙZj⁷
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MjbhuLbhuILDmEHhuZlaauKBtw&input=)

#### How it works

```
26ḶḂØAṙZj⁷  Main link. No arguments.

26Ḷ         Yield [0, ..., 25].
   Ḃ        Bit; compute the parity of each intger.
    ØAṙ     Rotate the alphabet by these amounts.
       Z    Zip; transpose rows and columns.
        j⁷  Join, separating by linefeeds.
```

Comment: Didn't `Y` exist back then? Also congrats for 100k rep!!

Comment: Thanks! I checked and, sadly, `Y` was added two days after the challenge was posted.

Comment: Because you could have golfed it further down to `26ḶḂØAṙZY`. But, as it is right now, it's still good.

Answer (score 7):

### PowerShell, <strike>49</strike> 43 bytes

TimmyD's remix:

```
65..89|%{-join[char[]]($_,++$_)*13};"ZA"*13
```

was, 49 bytes:

```
0..25|%{(""+[char]($_+++65)+[char]($_%26+65))*13}
```

[image: Example output]

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, <s>70</s> <s>68</s> 54 bytes

List based solution:

```python
L=map(chr,range(65,91))
for i in range(-26,0):print(L[i]+L[i+1])*13
```

But why create a list? Thanks LeakyNun:

```python
for i in range(26):print(chr(i+65)+chr(-~i%26+65))*13
```

Answer (score 6):

## R, <s>72</s> <s>67</s> <s>60</s> 56 bytes

```
write(matrix(LETTERS[c(1:26,2:26,1)],26,26,T),"",26,,"")
```

Thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312) for the extra 4 bytes off!

Old `rep`-based solution at 60 bytes:

```
for(i in 1:26)cat(rep(LETTERS[c(i,i%%26+1)],13),"\n",sep="")
```

See [here](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=BG1LX7Mx&version=5) on an online interpreter. Thanks to [@user5957401](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58162) for the extra 7 bytes off!

Old matrix-based solution at 72 bytes:

```
for(i in 1:26)cat(matrix(LETTERS[c(1:26,2:26,1)],26,26)[i,],"\n",sep="")
```

See [here](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=BG1LX7Mx&version=1) on an online interpreter.

Comment: if you change the indext to `i in 1:26` and then the letter selection to `LETTERS[c(i,i%%26+1)]` you can drop like 6 or 7 bytes

Comment: @user5957401 arf I was so stubbornly doing `(i+1)%%26` that it didn't occur to me to do the opposite! Thanks!

Comment: [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVIzexpCizQsPHNSTENSg4OlnD0MrITMcIRBhqxuqA2GY6IZo6SkogBpDS/P8fAA "R – Try It Online") using matrices again :)

Answer (score 6):

### [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 26 bytes

```
P
+'A
~
| S
+$ r2
 ,'
r'
```

Note the trailing unprintable characters on the last two lines.
[Try it online!](http://jellyfish.tryitonline.net/#code=UAorJ0EKfgp8IFMKKyQgcjIKICwnGgpyJxo&input=)

### Explanation

This is basically an arithmetic manipulation approach: make a 26×26 grid with alternating 0-1 pattern, add the index of each row to every element of the row, reduce mod 26, and add the ASCII value of `A`.
Characters in Jellyfish are just numbers with a special flag, and all arithmetic works on them as expected.

From bottom to top:

- The `'`s are character literals; they are followed by unprintables with ASCII code 26, and stand for those characters.
- The lower `r` computes the character range from 0 to 25.
- The `,` forms a pair from the two unprintable chars.
- The higher `r` is given argument `2`, and forms the range `[0 1]`.
- The `$` takes that range, and reshapes it into the shape given by its other argument, which is the pair of unprintables. This gives a 26×26 matrix of alternating rows `0 1 0 1 0 1 ...`
- The lower `+` adds the char range 0-25 to this matrix. The addition distributes on the rows, so row **i** is incremented by **i**. It's also converted to a char matrix, since the south argument consists of chars.
- The `~|` is modulus with flipped arguments: the south argument (the above char matrix) is reduced modulo the east argument (the `S` turns the argument-seeking process south, so this is the unprintable literal 26).
- The higher `+` adds the literal `A` to every coordinate of the resulting matrix.
- The `P` prints the result in matrix format, that is, each row on its own line without quotes.

Comment: I wanted to try to golf but then I saw the name of him who wrote the code.

Comment: @LeakyNun You can still try! Although 26 bytes is fitting for this challenge.

Answer (score 5):

### Perl, 26 bytes

*Solution from [@Dom Hastings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9365/dom-hastings). (12 bytes shorter than mine!)*
*-1 byte thanks to [@Ton Hospel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51507/ton-hospel)*

```pl
say+($_++,chop)x13for A..Z
```

Run with `-M5.010` or `-E` :

```
perl -E 'say+($_++,chop)x13for A..Z'
```

Comment: Managed to get this down to 33: `say+($_++,$_--=~/^./g)x13for A..Z`, but I'm sure there's a way to get a shorter one from: `say+($_++,$_--)x13for A..Z`...

Comment: Not sure why I have the `--` in there, it's not needed! O_o. 27: `say+($_++,/^./g)x13for A..Z`

Comment: @DomHastings Nicely done! I tried `say+($_,$_++)x13for A..Z` at first which didn't work, but it seems I should have push further into that direction!

Comment: `say+($_++,chop)x13for A..Z` saves one more byte

Comment: @TonHospel great, thanks for that.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 13 bytes

```
1Y2tn:!to~!+)
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MVkydG46IXRvfiErKQ&input=)

```
1Y2    % Predefined string literal: 'AB···Z'
tn:    % Duplicate, number of elements, range: gives [1, 2, ···, 26]
!      % Transpose into a column vector
to~!   % Duplicate and transform into [0, 1, 0, 1, ···, 1] using modulo 2
+      % Addition with broadcast. Gives 2D numeric array
)      % Index (modularly) into string. Implicitly display.
```

Answer (score 5):

**T-SQL 133 Bytes** (Golfed by : @t-clausen.dk)

```
SELECT REPLICATE(Char(number+65)+IIF(number=25,'A',Char(number+66)),13)FROM spt_values WHERE number<26and'P'=TYPE
```

**T-SQL , 151 Bytes**

Using CTE to generate sequence of number

```
;WITH n(a,v) AS(SELECT CHAR(65)+CHAR(66), 66 UNION ALL SELECT CHAR(v)+CHAR(v+1), v+1 FROM n WHERE v < 91)SELECT REPLICATE(REPLACE(a,'[','A'),13) FROM n
```

**T-SQL, 155 Bytes**

```
SELECT REPLICATE(Char(number+65)+ CASE WHEN number=25 THEN 'A' ELSE Char(number+66) END, 13) FROM master.dbo.spt_values  WHERE name IS NULL AND number < 26
```

Comment: I have golfed your **[answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/523082/print-an-alphabet-wave)** down to 113 characters.
I provided a very different answer in TSQL

Comment: @t-Clausen.dk That is excellent. Please post your answer. I would delete mine.

Comment: no reason to delete your answer, you can just use my fiddle to improve your answer. I already posted 1 hour ago ago, if you enjoy TSQL , you should take a look at my other answers. I made Fiddles for most of them

Answer (score 5):

## Vim, 31 bytes

```
:h<_↵↵↵YZZPJra0qqy2l13Plr↵25@qD
```

Where `↵` is the Return key.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 46 bytes

```julia
[println("$c$(c+1-26(c>89))"^13)for c='A':'Z']
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=W3ByaW50bG4oIiRjJChjKzEtMjYoYz44OSkpIl4xMylmb3IgYz0nQSc6J1onXQ&input=)

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
jCm.<G~!ZG
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jCm.%3CG~%21ZG&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
jCm.<G~!ZG
  m      G    Map over G, predefined to the lowercase alphabet.
              This will give 26 columns.
   .<G        Left shift (cyclically) G by
        Z     Z elements. Z is initialized to 0.
      ~!      After using its value, logical not Z. (0 -> 1, 1 -> 0)
 C            Transpose
j             Join on newlines
```

Comment: Nice, wish I knew as much as you do about Pyth

Answer (score 4):

### Brainfuck, <s>88</s> 86 bytes

```
++[[+>]<+<++]+>-[[->+>+<<]>>-]++++++++[<[++++++++<+<]>[>]<-]<<++<[>+++[->.<<.>]<<++.<]
```

Requires an interpreter with 8-bit cells and a tape not bounded on the left. [Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=KytbWys-XTwrPCsrXSs-LVtbLT4rPis8PF0-Pi1dKysrKysrKytbPFsrKysrKysrKzwrPF0-Wz5dPC1dPDwrKzxbPisrK1stPi48PC4-XTw8KysuPF0&input=)

Answer (score 3):

## Lua, <strike>80</strike> 65 Bytes.

```
s = string c = s.char for i=1,26 do print(s.rep(c(64+i)..c((65+(i%26))),13)) end
```

With help from Leaky Nun

```
c=("").char for i=1,26 do print((c(64+i)..c(65+i%26)):rep(13))end
```

Lua is a pretty inefficent language in regards to handling of strings and such, so this is the best I can narrow it down.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first post! You can save 5 bytes if you remove some unnecessary whitespace: `s=string c=s.char for i=1,26 do print(s.rep(c(64+i)..c((65+(i%26))),13))end`

Comment: `for i=1,26 do print(((64+i):char()..(65+(i%26)):char()):rep(13))end` (not tested)

Comment: Because `string.rep(x,13)` is basically `x:rep(13)`

Comment: Right! I forgot the string metatable defaultly indexes to the string library.

Comment: Although good, numbers such as 65+(i%26) don't count as strings unless stored as such. I'll work on a way to make that work for the hell of it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog v1](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/releases), <s>30</s> <s>24</s> 20 bytes

```
@Ab:"a"c:@Arz:{:12jc:@Nc.}a:wa
@Ab:"a"c:@Arze:12jcw@Nw\
@A$(:@Arze:12jcw@Nw\
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=QEEkKDpAQXJ6ZToxMmpjd0BOd1w)

Answer (score 3):

### 05AB1E, 12 bytes

```
ADÀ)øvyJ5Ø×,
```

**Explanation**

```
AD            # push 2 copies of the alphabet
  À           # rotate the 2nd one left by 1
   )ø         # add to list and zip
     v        # for each
      yJ      # join the pair
        5Ø×   # repeat it 13 times
           ,  # print with newline
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=QUTDgCnDuHZ5SjXDmMOXLA&input=)

Comment: I know this is an old question but i just can't help myself. `ADÀ)ø13×»` works as well with 9 bytes.

Comment: @Datboi: That does indeed work now, but unfortunately it didn't work at the time this question was posted :(

Answer (score 3):

## TSQL, 111 bytes

```
DECLARE @o varchar(702)='',@ int=1WHILE @<702SELECT @o+=CHAR(IIF(@%27=0,10,65+(@/27+1-@%27%2)%26)),@+=1PRINT @o
```

[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/523598/print-an-alphabet-wave)

Comment: Golfed even further to 99 bytes http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90659/58577

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>82</s> <s>75</s> <s>67</s> 66 bytes

```
Print@FromCharacterCode@PadLeft[{},26,{i-1,i}~Mod~26+65]~Do~{i,26}
```

Technically shorter, although it prints in lowercase instead of uppercase:

## Mathematica, 64 bytes

```
Print[""<>FromLetterNumber@Table[{i-1,i}~Mod~26+1,13]]~Do~{i,26}
```

Comment: Nice trick using `PadLeft`.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
⍉↑26⍴⌽∘⎕A¨⍳2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZC7DoJAEEV7voISCgWWh7WfAjEQEwK2JlYWCBvWaIzG1kcisdXCxsZPmR/Bu4EYobjJZufM2Zn1Z/FgMvfjNKppvZ@mlG1MhfJVWJMoKNsyj8STyjflR9THn4rEg9UA6lBRkigBD1BDzZeUqNiC@Fmn8iWvlCCwQGiNBZ068QNUQ@IXsNIIhDWS32u41Sxpw0FH3Zb1/P6PZDumslELA3G6ClOV/RiWL1vAbRztIFcLcNfg9YborYw/uRmMipOBpVWshTDERhzERbwv)

Requires `⎕IO←0`, so that `⍳2` evaluates to `0 1`.

#### How it works

```apl
⍳2     ⍝ 0 1
⌽∘⎕A¨  ⍝ Rotate the uppercase alphabet 0 and 1 times,
       ⍝ giving ["ABC..Z", "BCD..ZA"]
26⍴    ⍝ Cycle the two strings to the length of 26
⍉↑     ⍝ Promote to a matrix and transpose
```

---

### Bunch of 13- and 14-byte solutions

```apl
⍉↑26⍴⎕A(1⌽⎕A)
⍉↑26⍴0 1⌽¨⊂⎕A
(26⍴⍳2)⊖∘.⊣⍨⎕A
∪⍉↑26⍴↓2 27⍴⎕A
∪26⍴⍤1⍉2 27⍴⎕A
```

These are included in the TIO link above.

Answer (score 2):

## J, <s>20</s> 19 bytes

**1 byte thanks to miles.**

```
u:65+26|(+/2&|)i.26
```

[Online interpreter](http://tryj.tk/)

This is actually the program I used to generate the text in the challenge.

Comment: You can remove the `@`

Comment: `u:65+(|i.+/2|i.)26`

Answer (score 2):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, <s>141</s> 138 bytes

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(CHR(l+64)||CHR(MOD(l,26)+65))WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY l)FROM(SELECT CEIL(LEVEL/13)l FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<339)GROUP BY l;
```

Un-golfed

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(CHR(l+64)||CHR(MOD(l,26)+65))WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY l)
FROM   (
         SELECT CEIL(LEVEL/13)l 
         FROM   DUAL 
         CONNECT BY LEVEL<339  -- 26*13+1
       )
GROUP BY l
```

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL <strike>99</strike> 90 bytes

Saved 9 bytes thanks to @t-clausen.dk

`DECLARE @ INT=65z:PRINT REPLICATE(CHAR(@)+CHAR(IIF(@=90,65,@+1)),13)SET @+=1IF @<=90GOTO z`

Ungolfed:

```
DECLARE @CurrCharacter INT = 65; --ASCII decimal for 'A'
WHILE (@CurrCharacter <=90) --ASCII decimal for 'Z'
BEGIN 
   PRINT REPLICATE(
    REPLACE(CHAR(@CurrCharacter)+CHAR(@CurrCharacter+1),'[','A')
    ,13); --Replicate the current character and its neighbor 13 times. If the neighbor is '[' (ASCII code 91) then replace it with 'A'.
   SET @CurrCharacter+=1; --Go to the next letter
END
```

Comment: That is very nice, you can save another 9 bytes like [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/530331/programming-puzzles-code-golf)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
AuDÀø13×»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fsdTlcMPhHYbGh6cf2v3/PwA)

Posting because it beats the other 05AB1E answer and kinda uses a different method

*-2 with vectorisation*

### Explained

```
Au          # Push the uppercase alphabet. STACK = [A-Z]
  D         # Duplicate that. STACK = [A-Z, A-Z]
   À        # Rotate the alphabet left. STACK = [A-Z, Rotate_Left(A-Z)]
    ø       # Zip those two alphabets. STACK = ["AB", "BC", "CD", "DE", "EF", "FG", "GH", "HI", "IJ", "JK", "KL", "LM", "MN", "NO", "OP", "PQ", "QR", "RS", "ST", "TU", "UV", "VW", "WX", "XY", "YZ", "ZA"]
     13×»   # Repeat each 13 times and join with newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) `-nr`, 41 bytes

```
range(26)|[(.+range(26)%2)%26+65]|implode
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/78oMS89VcPITLMmWkNPG85TNQIiM20z09iazNyCnPyU1P///@UXlGTm5xX/180rAgA)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>88</s> 83 bytes

```js
_=>[..."ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"].map((c,i,a)=>(c+a[-~i%26]).repeat(13)).join`\n`
```

Where `\n` represents the literal newline character. Writing the alphabet out saved me three bytes today, but @LeakyNun saved me another five bytes.

Comment: Did it save you four bytes *yesterday*?

Comment: `_=>[...s="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"].map((c,i)=>(c+s[-~i%26]).repeat(13)).join\`\n\``

Comment: @LeakyNun No, just two, I'm afraid: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89297/17602

Comment: The `(c,i,a)` is watching you.

Answer (score 1):

**MATLAB, <s>47</s> 38 bytes**

```
a=(65:90)';char(repmat([a a([2:end 1])],1,13))

char(repmat([65:90;[66:90 65]]',1,13))
```

The first makes a column array of the alphabet in ASCII, appends a shifted copy as a column to its right, replicates the resulting 26*2 array 13 times columnwise, casts to a character array and prints by default.

The second makes a 2*26 array of alphabet and shifted alphabet, transposes it then continues as above.

Comment: You can save one byte using `[... '']` instead of `char(...)`.

Comment: And you can use simply `[65:90;66:90 65]` saving two bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### [Neoscript](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/neoscript), 59 bytes

```
a=('A:[]:'Z)+'Aeach n=0:[]:25console:log((a[n]+a[n+1])*13);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (using external library Enumerable) (84 bytes)

```
    n=>(w=_.Range(0,26)).WriteLine(x=>w.Write("",y=>String.fromCharCode((x+y%2)%26+65)))
```

Link to lib: https://github.com/mvegh1/Enumerable/

Code explanation: Create a range of ints starting at 0 for count of 26. Store into global variable w. For each, write a new line according to predicate. Predicate states to take "w" and write a joined string based off the passed predicate to Write. Predicate to Write uses an empty string as the join delimiter, and uses the current integer value from WriteLine ("x") and the current integer value from Write ("y") to calculate the correct string at that position

Edit: Removed extra parens to save 2 bytes

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 102 bytes

```
<?php $a='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA';$i=-1;while($i++<25){echo str_repeat(substr($a,$i,2),13)."\n";}
```

Comment: You can remove the quotes from the Alphabet string. Replace \n with an actual enter instead of \n. Stole that idea from @insertusernamehere. So check his answer for what I mean. Edit: Also use the short-tag notation <?.  You also do not need a space after <?. So `<?$a='ABC'` also works.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 41 bytes

```
26.times{|i|puts [*?A..?Z,?A][i,2]*''*13}
```

Answer (score 1):

## **C (86 bytes):**

```c
for(int c=-11,n=-26;++n<1;){while(c++){printf("%c%c",90+n,n?91+n:65);}c=-11;puts("");}
```

My first attempt on a Code Golf challenge.

Some answers are really impressive!

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 65 bytes

Well, this is pretty straight forward:

```
for(;$i<26;)echo str_repeat(chr(65+$i).chr(65+(++$i%26)),13)."
";
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 107 bytes

My first attempt at a submission to PPCG

Golfed:

```
var l="";int i=0,j=0;for(;i<26;i++){for(;j<26;j++)l+=(char)(((j%2)+i)%26+65);Console.WriteLine(l);l="";j=0;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
var l="";
int i=0,j=0;
for(;i<26;i++){
    for(;j<26;j++)l+=(char)(((j%2)+i)%26+65);
        Console.WriteLine(l);
    l="";j=0;
}
```

Pretty sure this adheres to standards! Would love to hear any potential improvements.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 87 bytes

```
void c(){for(int i=0;i<703;)System.out.print((char)(i++%27>0?65+(i/27+i%27%2)%26:10));}
```

Based on [*@orlp*'s amazing answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89314/52210).

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/SaE1DY)

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[]a){
    c();
  }
  
  static void c(){
    for(int i=0; i<703;){
        System.out.print((char)(i++%27 > 0
                                  ? 65 + (i/27+i%27%2)%26
                                  :10));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 53 bytes

```
i=0;exec'print(chr(i+65)+chr(-~i%26+65))*13;i+=1;'*26
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, SBCL, 86 bytes

```
(dotimes(i 26)(format t"~13@{~a~:*~}~%"(subseq"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA"i(+ i 2))))
```

#### Explanation

```
(dotimes(i 26);loop from i=0 to i=25
(format t"~13@{~a~:*~}~%"(subseq"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA"i(+ i 2))))
;print 13 times pairs of "AB", "BC", ... , "ZA"
```

Answer (score 1):

#### c64 basic v2, <strike>95</strike> <strike>93</strike> <strike>85</strike> <strike>83</strike> 77 bytes

```
0fOy=65to90:l$="":a$=cH(y)+cH(y+1+(y=90)*26)
1fOx=0to12:l$=l$+a$:nE:?l$:nE
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Trial instructions are in my [previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142638/14149).

Comment: can you switch out 0..25 for 65..90 in the first line? e.g. `0fOy=65to90:l$="":a$=chr$(y):b$=chr$(1+y):ify=90tHb$="a"` for -3 bytes?

Comment: @streetster Thanks! And I switched to conditional operator to avoid the if-then! :-) It is already 85. Screenshot follows.

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
Z«Z¹'⁰∙I
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=WiVBQlolQjklMjcldTIwNzAldTIyMTlJ)

Explanation:

```
Z         push the uppercase alphabet
 «        put its first letter at the end
  Z       push the alphabet once again
   ¹      wrap in array: ["BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"]
    '⁰∙   multiply vertically 13 times
       I  rotate clockwise
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 64 bytes

```bash
f()(tr A-Z B-ZA|tee >(((i++<25))&&f);echo)
printf ZA%.s {a..m}|f
```

Credit to [seshoumara's `sed` answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92874/69583) for the idea of translating `A-Z` to `B-ZA`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P01DU6OkSMFRN0rBSTfKsaYkNVXBTkNDI1Nb28bIVFNTTS1N0zo1OSNfk6ugKDOvJE0hylFVr1ihOlFPL7e2Ju3/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Visual Basic .NET (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/visualbasic/), 140 bytes

```vb
Module M
Sub Main
Dim I,J,S
For I=1To 26
S=""
For J=0To 11
S+=Chr$(I+64)+Chr$(I Mod 26+65)
Next
Console.WriteLine(S)
Next
End Sub
End Module
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU5NC8IwFLu/X/EYHja6iRPtraepsGG9VPC8j4KFrQ@2Vvz3tWyeEpKQ5GMW345F1y6mL6x2xUSWQpA0@FGjBOU7lK2xcDET1nmTK7jRjLUon4RHDkokyao04hCVsgTFRPWed2nN@CljG8XYF9OMnzN46K@DiuxCo96/ZuP03Vidqr9ztQPG0RW3FyH8AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MY-BASIC](https://github.com/paladin-t/my_basic), 77 bytes

```vb
For I=1 To 26
For J=0 To 12
Print Chr(I+64)+Chr(I Mod 26+65)
Next
Print;
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y63UTUoszkz@/98tv0jB09ZQISRfwciMC8TzsjUA8QyNuAKKMvNKFJwzijQ8tc1MNLXBLAXf/BSgUm0zU00uv9SKEogqazD7/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>78, 72,</s> 67 bytes

```php
<?php $s='A';while($s!='AA')echo str_repeat($s++.(--$s)[0],13)."
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go0BBpdhW3VHdujwjMydVQ6VYEchzVNdMTc7IVyguKYovSi1ITSwBSmhr62no6qoUa0YbxOoYGmvqKXEpWf//DwA)

Comment: Instead of striking out old answers, just keep their bytecount in the header and strike those out. The revision history is sufficient in case you want to see older solutions.

Comment: @Timtech good point, thank you, Sir :)

Comment: Glad to help you out @Link, keep it up:)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
⍉(⎕a⌽⍨2|⊢)⌸⎕a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG9qZv6jtgkG////f9TbqQHkJz7q2fuod4VRzaOuRZqPenaAhAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
Ｅ²⁶⎇﹪ι²α⁺ΦαμA⟲⁶
```

Link is to verbose version of code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExCoAwDADA3Wc4JZAuDu4OugkifiDWiIVqIFbB18e7eLBF5ezeczygaWkRu9g@GHV7skKiBolpys8NQ8pFDJhOpLqrEbGatXARaNHdQ9jkFVv1Tvvn4f0B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang/blob/master), 34 bytes

```
;=a 65;W>90aO*+AaA=a+1a 13O*"ZA"13
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKSyNLCeSYK/2bGSKZCFFHYEsJJeqA18iZBlUK8s@SYblCPfXc909LxrZJne5Wz5Y1szTPd3P9HT3mLh/E8ffXqR5nC0nyV5ZTdL5y9tR2xzJ0uvGUFw9LJIVUJHmN42hKp0JzCSZpnnCsoxl8/yGPtp69MPpx3fMr18vPpyzoH7968E5261fj07fsJ/r1/OPzK/BRycXBvb044kB/Xj67uDiL3bJmY0fXfYv/yeuZw8uYFkxGd9GBXN4LWCiwFatYjRiu/Xc6eEnnMxhkjz6yvD73t4KBpchDLoJmCzjCGxgXp@dnRAIP/bJyQH6Zhhy/lYAQN6w9S7Klgnnl/mYt9vkB@zK5Tg87xyeHdnfhmHE/vTT8NPoz1505vQOooMw6vkR83fOnM7fDjr@zjcOwM5QyDognEQzFqKWYbsNSy2iokxszh7brTSvWDpst2CUlnWZM13mMYyQcAzv1Wzhlov8MhiHj57rPYGOVgrqCA9PDwdevUL16YLd36ZVUi6iOGm34HuW2DAO4rYww2Wdq@oqv5peFezx6XJs88GLDidTWumU2drakFkvLM6ECjW6BaNXOQz3emIE7GwlWZmYA0/CnPg2iX9j03nB8uXsOilKaQ@z03KS3qSV0gqrozu@qz0ST4f5HusxR1re63HWZ5ZnwRJoacpZkVTLImcqUIQYxcpw1Ya7qEij6yxRVoAR2fw@KewY1lOGsK9fmTIupreYiPhscUlPusH1NPRd2KNQD69Yh0dPhihA8slyYeOWMslpn8HbusEiEZRCmzDjyrJqmzqW2DQQBg@0UQyUQOKA72DZIiorVt0moCwqKgDLDXAUo7ihMUdPlLHGeXrWWPj0OW10qyaDzMfQrdJ5DmZjxHpjMC1WjJTLxQIJ5yqq1IhJvxl/QLtBNupQobzIIY4hiWHkSssFKx8sfdLFwBEOYEIbYCJDM1WQUQ4UrtpoN5oaZdk8tnc91@foIA5rJ8jBfJllUfFgOlrvz7mxPe8tbRktKOWX@Yo0LeHjEjIpbPL04PD1my@/bp38cmY4bKq9TjfqDdb1bjUUvz2@eEZjlRSkMson7B/LSL2i2jtziZ31JQQBby3NxfEGLkh4tyncxDxRqiyWOe7QUCZip5qXtsqVdAAgtKs0ZjR7vZxeBrtjaYfY6C6lB21AuYBjVU1tgIL/21k26ai8Q4XIRSWrCuBQaAWixIn1G7g9KABNP9F5jMV91qmKZdKBGNTjGJIwPo0gg@BEByOrU5OAfqLvshYRHZ9fz@cZzFw3GXjW19qt7znk/LhHppnXa2ZmaGP@h9oIQVvNs8w2TXWZ50KF@B9MztdMxir87uD9qYu1WAQavB5f@p7nQTiBK/Cq3sr0n8nniuFjaMSo4S0yAG8ufgT0uRP6qqRjhsOqjg/6DMRjBwBHxyeHDptCchy2dGjL9TANx9HCzZKcOgCDK9UqCc7g3D1Hxqog1iYsbVhw7JR6CajFe8TFEIpKipM6b8SzxcoOEEnpuE4hSFM6xmXK@7SKb20HmFnrrIAjJv9irFPWgTVguIoAhEgo9maQhXmXnJLqZXfYCFk@pCpcI6gFrQosXdSFXo75Yx1m0EBRbhcLn8PCTd0FZDybd73fp/hXI98DErQKjm6SKoMG0u7SXnZxh7BETtKcD9OpbdN@YkMQ3xZoiwtxyrnY5tAbbrQVHpzaALHeoVhPdI6YDSQhQ2UvkiRzZ23l69ofgdczb@oZlDQp1pgvgMFogPgLF/NFktvGwm6n6FCrAFaFM1EpIR7DwNv9mcZlc2GLjmQKpk/QKWjhIGRd7O8ADr0DveEasLQKLxsGWS@kVghPLCC5pBv00FpENWpwQhaYPUtNY@3Jr@BJ8ju0cXja1/zcauw63RO2MJOtAU/WwgNWyZq8GPBfrIHsEzcEss58sgJ1TqkttrEGcVWERqNdXjeWa@lQiV5Qc2hvlyjYPAzrwkAntD7mupBJeaeGqgksL0mUS7XPlTBZs8wdkLlFsnBWs4AHQ1x8kDSxnw3qWLdLl6t@H6Fj0eZeUbvdUmZtv3RKsMeGN87UUSsM85dVqXZfx4To9YRBPW0Q5UnIl5iSMbSM7RHddKu52@Kmimjo@5mKpUDsOfa/dBjEBhAKh/GUh8rLgG8O1Tiq1EN2nX6vpomr76iLQzfq0rOSOUL61V@LTiPasVVv2iuEnHp3NrCwWp438OCs8SD2dRMLsw2uOYQJTSUkADXIpgwZWldwyUPQsN8nfZIoKpmrGy0YrRqn/9V3iXm1mZjt7wptbxb6O7HZcEhcHWgsML0cStoF6yHr@5plwgL1Ppyzvg9nzDfBwQ@i9yA9NrBhiFBad6BGPEU5ER2MPMl1wKldcULiv716IGiSXIE7AiVYLDHwHa8Mt0mRWCXL59BDp1mV5uw@egDe2GQOd9IquUkKkFnM8ySv0ghvEXCS5@w@YbfRXQJAqQjhFZtF@RLC5@EljqJ318g4UEFMlMuswh8NaHGd8BSkb2LUkiuUmXIasqIe9T2P9J43RMP2GiiP7udRhrXxAbzOJ1kyYV9qs79oLY/4TTRmxiK1MyNU1u@rd07wloQ6hulPOg/uUbCuFD5Meo28GDaz4j4zD/@eeQxQdCB/g@syAdhnjUaRBl1mZEPU4QlJVXIDUQcQuxVCtTG6oBEcSgyt@WQ@YLNkFi8wzHI2@rL//7oy@gNcGSlXtjb4EkpfpCv7z7MvVt1gMk7vswYg0IhAFdCtTXbWL9o9lXlMBdq8bp3@0JdNtWHflJSpRMt//W/kZQ4y1Gj5oTUw0Y02dxUb1lm3Of3DFxnV29Y3GcS1GrcZnQoJgxrHYUPaSJMogYheT4sJkz@Be@JXL7PRbHjHzN5Fih03u3aEGvL7wWDHoOWtuDKERofVMwvQ@h0plxcPV5@FnUZDeyGIXlE6XC15waaSt8N1HxBo6V0a/A8NERqGT9yKWDf/uh0ye6MAPMRVez42SdQgiPgXk/QgRE@eBFh9kkwjSJLgmeow0xwm0wn9iBTFFZQpazu2sOfEEc6eucWiMl0DoRuUPyTMojTHZpVFxU3sklLHge93HH@uovsl/kvH9sia5jXu6du/AQ)

Expanded code:

```
;=a 65
;WHILE > 90 a
  OUTPUT * (+(ASCII a) (ASCII (= a(+ 1 a)))) 13 
OUTPUT (* "ZA" 13)
```

There's probably a better way to deal with the last row, but I don't know it.

Another 34-byte solution:

```
;=a 0W>26aO*+A+65aA+65%=a+1a 26 13
```

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 51 bytes

```
!()=join(["$x$(x+1-26(x>89))"^13for x='A':'Z'],"
")
```

Initial golfing.

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>77</s> <s>74</s> 71 bytes

Basically the same as the [Python answer inspired by LeakyNun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89283/print-an-alphabet-wave/89288#89288), Thanks to owacoder for `puts`
:

```c
f(i,j){for(i=0;++i<27;puts(""))for(j=13;--j;printf("%c%c",i+64,i%26+65));}
```

Usage:

```c
f();
```

<s>While  [mathematically](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(26-n)%20mod%2026%20%3D%20(-n)%20mod%2026) `(26-n)%26 == (-n)%26`, this is not true for C, otherwise these two bytes can be shaved off.</s> Using a count up loop for `i` resolves the problem

Comment: You can save two bytes by counting from 64: `f(i,j){for(i=64;++i<91;printf("\n"))for(j=13;--j;printf("%c%c",i,i%91+65));}`

Comment: Use `puts("")` instead of `printf("\n")` for printing a newline.

Comment: @Advancid no you can't. that `i%95` does not work

Comment: @owacoder Ah, good old `puts`. Only had `putchar` in mind.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>139</s> 137 bytes

```
()->{for(int i=65,j=1;;j++){if(j>25){j=++i<91?1:0;System.out.println();
if(j==0)break;}System.out.print((char)i+""+(char)(i>89?65:i+1));}}
```

Comment: chaning `j==26` to `j>25` allow you to save 1 byte. using multiple print statements when you are golfing in java cost you badly, and you could refactor it to use single print statement

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript(ES5), <strike>107</strike> 99 bytes

```
for(var s="",i=-1;++i<676;)i&&!(i%26)&&(s+="\n"),s+=String.fromCharCode((i/26+i%2)%26+65);alert(s);
```

Comment: `console.log` => `alert`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Made another small change as well. This is the part I'd really like to change "i&&!(i%26)", surely there's a better way of doing both checks here at once, or at least in a more concise way! I'd love any suggestions here!

Answer (score 0):

## [RETURN](https://github.com/molarmanful/RETURN), 23 bytes

```
'A'[␊'B'[␊'A␈13␋␄'␊°␇␂,
```

<kbd>[Try it here.](http://molarmanful.github.io/RETURN/)</kbd>

NOTE: Use the "Insert String" button and paste the above code in.

## Explanation

Basically generates `A-Z` and `B-Z and A at the end` on the stack. Then the stack is duplicated 13 times, transposed, joined with a newline, and outputted.

Due to a bug that I just can't fix, `'A'[␊${25@}13␋␄'␊°␇␂,` does not work.

Comment: A language using `␊` instead of a literal newline is weird...

Comment: No, I'm just putting it there to avoid confusion; newlines are range commands, so having ␊ there emphasizes that. It's the same with the other unprintables.

Answer (score 0):

## C# - <strike>159</strike> 138 bytes

```
var a="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA";for(int i=0;i<26;i++){for(int j=0;j<14;j++){Console.Write("{0}{1}",a[i],a[i+1]);}Console.WriteLine();}
```

Comment: If you add A at the end of the alphabet you can change `(i+1)%26` to `i+1`

Comment: The alphabet can also be `var` and you don't need the `.ToCharArray()` as a string is already just that.

Comment: Oh, thank you! This was my first time code golfing, so I'm happy to learn more.

Comment: Creating the row in a variable and replacing the inner for with a while saves at least 13 additional bytes.

Comment: You can save a few bytes by using string interpolation like this: `Console.Write($"{a[i]}{a[i+1]}")` which makes it 135 bytes

Answer (score 0):

## JAVA 9, <s>103</s> 97 bytes

it works on JShell, provided by Java9 SDK.

```
for(int c=64,i;++c<91;)for(i=0;i<26;)System.out.print((char)((c-13+i%2)%26+65)+(i++<25?"":"\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 13 bytes

```
GGt\a+]w-*,_X
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=GGt%5Ca%2B%5Dw-%2a%2C_X)

Answer (score 0):

### [ListSharp](https://github.com/timopomer/ListSharp), 236 bytes

```
ROWS x=ROWSPLIT "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,T,S,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,A" BY [","]
[FOREACH NUMB IN 1 TO 26 AS i]
{
STRG t =""
[FOREACH NUMB IN 1 TO 13 AS j]
{
STRG e=GETLINE x [i]
STRG r=GETLINE x [i+1]
STRG t=t+e+r
}
ROWS s=s+t
}
SHOW=s
```

Feel free to comment if you want anything to be explained to you

Execution screenshot:
[image: Execution screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 6, 50 bytes

```
say .join x 13 for flat('A'..'Z','A').rotor(2=>-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## EXCEL: 53 bytes

```
=REPT(CHAR(ROW(A1)+64)&CHAR(MOD(ROW(A1),26)+65),13)
```

Place in A1 and drag to desired length of wave (in this case, 26, one cell for each letter).

Answer (score 0):

Improving on @gabe3886's answer (new account and not able to comment)

### PHP <strike>94</strike> 92 Bytes

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<26;)echo str_repeat(substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA',$i++,2),13)."\n";
```

However if you suppress notices, it's <strike>92</strike> 90 bytes

```
<?php for(;@$i<26;)echo str_repeat(substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA',@$i++,2),13)."\n";
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. You can golf this down to *79 bytes*: `for(;$i<26;)echo str_repeat(substr(ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA,$i++,2),13)."↵";`. Replace `↵` with an actual line break. As an additional note: You don't need to include the PHP opening tag and you don't need to handle notices.

Comment: You can even save another *6 bytes*, with a total of *73 bytes*: `for(;$i<26;)echo str_repeat(substr(implode(range(A,Z)).A,$i++,2),13)."↵";`

Comment: @insertusernamehere: Thanks! I wasn't too clear on the rules for this exchange (IE: does it include just functional code (no <?php tag) and/or would warnings be considered part of the output). I noticed in your second comment that `range(A,Z)` don't have the A and Z characters quoted. Is that abusing another PHP "feature"?

Comment: Yes, I've removed the quotes in both suggestions. When you run a string without quotes it should prompt something like `Notice: Use of undefined constant` which is fine here. But be careful, this won't work on strings with whitespaces or special characters etc.

Comment: Right. I remember now. PHP will assume it's the literal character "A"(or "Z" or whatever), which is the same reason "foo $bar[baz]" interpolation works without the curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

## Logo, 93 bytes

Here's a non-graphical Logo solution.  Try it online with [Calormen.com's interpreter](http://www.calormen.com/jslogo/).

```
to m:c type char 65+modulo:c 26end
to b:a repeat 13[m:a-1 m:a] pr" end
repeat 26[b repcount]
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, Z (90) bytes

```
for(i=65,b=66;i<91;++i,b=b<90?++b:65)console.log(Array(14).join(String.fromCharCode(i,b)))
```

*To learn*:

```
var start = 65,
    end = 90;

for (var i = start, b = i+1; i <= end; ++i) {
    var chars = String.fromCharCode(i, b);
    /* repeat chars 14 times */
    console.log(Array(14).join(chars));
}
```

Comment: What is that Z?

Comment: @EriktheGolfer You know, Z in ASCII is 90 bytes (\x5a)

Answer (score 0):

**VIM, 42**

```
:h<_↵↵↵YZZP:s/./&\r/g↵^25↑y↑pG2↑aa↓^ggy13P
```

where:

- `↵` is return,
- ^ is ctrl + v
- ↑ is the up arrow
- ↓ is escape

I'm sure this can be golfed more. I'm new to VIM so any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**python 3, <s>92</s> 90 bytes**

```
a=65
b=66
for i in range(312):
    if a>89:b=65
    print(chr(a)+chr(b),end="")
    if (i+1)%12<1:
        a+=1
        b+=1
        print()
```

**python 2, 80 bytes**

```
a=65
b=66
for i in range(312):
    if a>89:b=65
    print chr(a)+chr(b),
    if (i+1)%12<1:
        a+=1
        b+=1
        print
```

This program outputs `AB AB AB AB...` rather than `ABABABAB...` I'm not sure if this is allowed, but it's the best I can come up with.

**EDIT:**

Thanks @User902383 for you comment on @TAsk's post allowing me to shave off 2 bytes.

And thanks @NoOneIsHere for suggesting that I move to python 2 instead of 3, I've included a second program in python 2 with a new byte count.

Comment: You can remove the soace before `b=65`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I already had mentally omitted that when I counted it, just not taken it out of the code. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: If you switch to python 2, you can replace `print()` with `print`, and `print(...,end='')` to `print ...,` (trailing comma).

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 64 bytes

Can anyone improve on this?

```scala
(('A'to'Z'):+'A').sliding(2).map(_.mkString*13).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7, 65 bytes

Python 2 alternative using a recursive function

```
def l(a=0):
 print(chr(a+65)+chr(-~a%26+65))*13
 if a<25:l(-~a)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Vitsy, 29 bytes

So, instead of doing the typical thing, I used my two-dimensional stacking to generate the alphabets and then offset them by one from each other, alternating back and forth between them.

```
9a*d5*Hd\[:{:}]Y?y\[y\[O?]aO]

9a*d5*H                        Push an alphabet to the stack.
9a*                                 Push 90 to the stack (character code 'Z')
   d5*                              Push 65 to the stack (character code 'A')
      H                             Pop a, b, push range (a, b)

       d\[:{:}]                Establish the other stacks, while alternating.
       d\[    ]                     Do the bracketed code 13 times.
          : :                       Clone the stack.
           {                        Put the top item of the stack on the bottom.
             }                      Put the bottom item of the stack on the top.
               Y                    Discard a stack. (13*2+1-1 = 26)
                ?                   Rotate right a stack (we start on 'A' now)
                 y\[y\[O?]aO]  Output.
                 y\[        ]       Repeat the code in brackets number of stacks times (26).
                    y\[  ]          Repeat the code in brackets number of stack times (26).
                       O            Pop a, print a as a character.
                        ?           Go right a stack.
                          aO        Output a newline.
```

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=OWEqZDUqSGRcWzp7On1dWT95XFt5XFtPP11hT10&input=)

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, <strike>70</strike> <strike>66</strike> 64 Bytes

```
<?$a=A;$b=B;while($a!=AA)echo str_repeat($a++.($b++)[0],13)."
";
```

3 bytes short (if I would remove the `<?` as well) from @insertusernamehere answer. So close!

EDIT:
Actually got it to 66 bytes (64 without the `<?`)! Doing A and B without quotes actually seem to work. Seems to be the shortest PHP one as time of write :D

EDIT 2:
Also removed " " from AA. Still seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, <strike>149</strike>, <strike>115</strike>, <s>111</s>, 106 bytes

```
for i in {0..25};{
printf $(printf %b%b \\`printf %o $[i+65]` \\`printf %o $[-~i%26+65]`)%.s {a..m};echo
}
```

(thanks @manatwork, saved <strike>34</strike>, 4 more bytes)

## [Bash, 140 bytes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/304923/4252)

(thanks @steeldriver)

```
for i in {0..25}; do printf "$(printf '%b%b' \\$(printf '%03o' $((i+65))) \\$(printf '%03o' $((-~i%26+65))))%.0s" {1..13}; printf \\n; done
```

Save to `<file>` and run as: `/bin/bash <file>`

Comment: `$((…))` → `$[…]`, `'%b%b'` → `%b%b`, `printf \\n` → `echo`, inner `$(…)` → `\`…\``, `do … done` → `{ … }`, `%.0s` → `%.s`, `{1..13}` → `{a..m}`. (Some of those you may find in [Tips for golfing in Bash](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15279/tips-for-golfing-in-bash).)

Comment: Sorry, but `{` and `}` need separators around them. But there are still single quotes to remove around `printf`'s format strings and what I forgot earlier, no need for the double quotes either. http://pastebin.com/s1h75e5i

Comment: One more thing: 65..90 in octal is 101..132, so they take 3 digits anyway, so `%03o` → `%o`.

Comment: Sorry, seems I not explained the error well enough. As the code you posted failed with “line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `{printf'”, I edited it. Feel free to revert if you disagree.

Comment: @manatwork copy-paste error on my part, thanks (-:

Answer (score 0):

### GNU sed, 95 bytes

```sed
s,^,@@@@@@@@@@@@@,;s,@,AB,g
:;p
y,ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA,
/^Z/!b
```

I wish the 'y' command had this syntax: `y,A-Z,B-ZA,`.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 56

```
for k in range(26):print(chr(k+65)+chr((k+1)%26+65))*13
```

Comment: Ah, I had a look at your answer, @Karl Napf. You used a sneaky method of golfing two bits away from my solution. Thank you for teaching me something new :]

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 52 bytes

```
for($a=A;$a!=AA;)echo str_pad("\n",27,$a++.$a[0],0);
```

Can JavaScript beat this? Run with `-r`.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 98 Bytes

```
for(var j=371,s="";j<1333;j+=37){for(i=0;i<13;i++)s+=j.toString(36).replace("100","za");s+="<br>"}
```

[Try it here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mRgzYO)

Comment: Is that a typo? This doesn't look like 12 bytes to me. (I think it's 98 bytes.)

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 80

```
time {puts [string repe [format %c%c [expr [incr i]+64] [expr $i%26+65]] 13]} 26
```

### [demo](http://rextester.com/VJGU77565)

---

## tcl, 86

```
while {[incr i]<27} {puts [string repe [format %c%c [expr $i+64] [expr $i%26+65]] 13]}
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/XZRB60396)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Unix utilities, <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```bash
dc "-e65[d257*1+16 52^65535/*POP1+d91>x]dsxx"|tr [ A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@SrKCkm2pmGp1iZGquZahtaKZgahRnZmpqbKqvFeAfYKidYmloVxGbUlxRoVRTUqQQreD4/z8A)

Test run:

```bash
dc "-e65[d257*1+16 52^65535/*POP1+d91>x]dsxx"|tr [ A
ABABABABABABABABABABABABAB
BCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBC
CDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCD
DEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDE
EFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEF
FGFGFGFGFGFGFGFGFGFGFGFGFG
GHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGH
HIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHI
IJIJIJIJIJIJIJIJIJIJIJIJIJ
JKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKJK
KLKLKLKLKLKLKLKLKLKLKLKLKL
LMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLM
MNMNMNMNMNMNMNMNMNMNMNMNMN
NONONONONONONONONONONONONO
OPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOP
PQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQ
QRQRQRQRQRQRQRQRQRQRQRQRQR
RSRSRSRSRSRSRSRSRSRSRSRSRS
STSTSTSTSTSTSTSTSTSTSTSTST
TUTUTUTUTUTUTUTUTUTUTUTUTU
UVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUV
VWVWVWVWVWVWVWVWVWVWVWVWVW
WXWXWXWXWXWXWXWXWXWXWXWXWX
XYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXY
YZYZYZYZYZYZYZYZYZYZYZYZYZ
ZAZAZAZAZAZAZAZAZAZAZAZAZA
```

Answer (score 0):

## Windows batch, 155 bytes

```
@set s=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA
@set/ac=-1
:L
@set/ac+=1
@call set t=%%s:~%c%,2%%
@for /l %%i in (1,1,13) do @cd|set/p=%t%
@echo(
@if %t% neq ZA @goto l
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 50 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs a wave to the range `[A1:Z26]` on the ActiveSheet object

```vb
[A1:Z26]="=Char(Mod(Row()+IsEven(Column()),26)+64)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), 19 bytes

```
{B26'P*13Z~}+(C65;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P@/2snITD1Ay9A4qq5WW8PZzNS69v9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

I haven't been there

```
VG*13+N@G=hZ
```

Explanation:

```
VG       In the lowercase alphabet...
  *13     13 times...
  +N@G=hZ The current item concatenated with alphabet[++Z]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P8xdy9BY28/B3TYj6v9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 23 bytes

**Solution:**

```
`c$65+26#'a,'1_27#a:!26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/PyFZxcxU28hMWT1RR90w3shcOdFK0cjs/38A)

**Explanation:**

```
`c$65+26#'a,'1_27#a:!26 / solution
                    !26 / range 0..25
                  a:    / save as 'a'
               27#      / 27 take, wraps to make ABC...XYZA
             1_         / 1 drop, take off leading A
          a,'           / concatenate each element with each of a (AB,BC,etc)
      26#'              / 26 take each, wraps to get ABABAB... BCBCBC... etc
   65+                  / add 65, vectorised (65=A in ASCII)
`c$                     / cast to characters
```

**Bonus:**

Here are a couple of other ways to get the result:

**24 chars:** [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/PyFZxcxUW9vITFlD0cjM2jDeyFwZyND8/x8A)

```
`c$65++26#(!26;1_27#!26)
```

**27 chars:** [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/38hMWV3bQMEwXt3ITMHIXDnGKiFZxcxUW9HI7P9/AA)

```
26#'+0 1_'26 27#\:`c$65+!26
```

Answer (score 0):

## q/kdb+, 19 bytes

**Solution:**

```
26#'.Q.A,'1_27#.Q.A
```

**Explanation:**

Shorter and different to my `oK` solutions as we have a shortcut to the uppercase alphabet by means of `.Q.A`. As always, interpreted right-to-left

```
26#'.Q.A,'1_27#.Q.A / solution
               .Q.A / shortcut to uppercase alphabet, ABC..XYZ
            27#     / 27 take, wraps to get ABC...XYZA
          1_        / 1 drop, drop first element to give BCD...XYZA
    .Q.A,'          / concatenate each left/right lists, so AB, BC, CD etc
26#'                / 26 take each, gives ABABA.. BCBCB... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 52 bytes

```
Column[""<>#~Table~13&/@Partition[Alphabet[],2,1,1]]
```

-1 byte from Martin Ender

Comment: Infix notation for `Table` saves a byte.

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 69 bytes

```vb
For I=1To 26
For J=0To 12
?Chr$(I+64)+Chr$(Mod(I,26)+65);
Next
?
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3y2/SMHT1jAkX8HIjAvE8bI1AHIMjbjsnTOKVDQ8tc1MNLXBTN/8FA1PHSMzTW0zU01rLr/UihIuezD1/z8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), 83 bytes

```
0ForI=1To26:ForJ=0To12:?Left$(Chr$(I+64),1)+Left$(Chr$(IMod26+65),1);:NextJ:?:NextI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fwC2/yNPWMCTfyMwKyPSyNQjJNzSysvdJTStR0XDOKFLR8NQ2M9HUMdTURhbzzU8xMtM2MwVJWFv5pVaUeFnZg2nP//8B)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-n`, 18 bytes

```
(z.z)@>_@<2X13M,26
```

Pip doesn't have transpose, so I just took two letter substrings and repeated them.

`-n` joins lists with newlines.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fo0qvStPBLt7BxijC0NhXx8js////unkA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ØA,Ɲẋ€13j⁷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDEedY3Mf7up@1LTG0DjrUeP2//8B)

Noncompeting probably because some of the atoms are new.

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 10 bytes

```
kA:ǓZv∑13*
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=kA%3A%C7%93Zv%E2%88%9113*&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
kA         # Uppercase alphabet
  :ǓZ      # Zip with a copy  rotated one to the left
     v∑    # Sum each
       13* # Repeat each 13x
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;B¬£BéÓYvÃy
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=O0Kso0Lp01l2w3k)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 78 bytes

```python
a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for i in range(len(a)):print(a[i]+a[-~i%26])*13
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9FWKTEpOSU1LT0jMys7Jzcvv6CwqLiktKy8orJKiSstv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VSMnNU8jUVPTqqAoM69EIzE6M1Y7MVq3LlPVyCxWU8vQ@P9/AA)

Comment: Is this a valid -2 shave: `a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza"\nfor i in range(len(a)):print(a[i]+a[-~i])*13`? it errors, but iirc the meta consensus is to ignore error output

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 46 bytes

```
p=A
for c ({B..Z} A)<<<${(el:52::$p$c:)}&&p=$c
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY39QpsHbnS8osUkhU0qp309KJqFRw1bWxsVKo1UnOsTI2srFQKVJKtNGvV1ApsVZIhuqCaYYYAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `j`, 8 bytes

```
mmṘZṠ13×
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJqIiwiIiwibW3huZha4bmgMTPDlyIsIiIsIiIsIjMuNC4xIl0=)