# A very long Terza Rima

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity, alphabet

## Description

Output the rhyme scheme for a very long Terza Rima.

## Input

None.

## Output

```
ABA
BCB
CDC
DED
EFE
FGF
GHG
HIH
IJI
JKJ
KLK
LML
MNM
NON
OPO
PQP
QRQ
RSR
STS
TUT
UVU
VWV
WXW
XYX
YZY
```

## Rules

You can pick between separating stanzas with whitespace or newlines, so either:

```
ABA BCB...
```

OR

```
ABA
BCB
...
```

A single trailing whitespace allowed per line and one trailing newline allowed.

Output can be either uppercase or lowercase.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes for each language wins.

Comment: Is a list of lines okay?

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terza_rima your ending is wrong. It should end with either Z or ZZ.

Comment: Can there be additional output beyond the rhyme scheme? This might save me a few bytes.

Comment: @NK1406 Nope sorry.

Comment: @totallyhuman String array is fine.

Comment: @Chris I found it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyme_scheme). Which says it can be YZY,

Comment: @LiefdeWen: Huh. Weird. Sadly I don't know which is correct or I'd edit wikipedia to be consistent. :)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89283/print-an-alphabet-wave)

Comment: @LiefdeWen From your Wiki I see “YZY/Z” or “YZY/ZZ” or “YZY/ZYZ.” No “YZY and that’s it.”

Answer (score 25):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>51</s> <s>50</s> 49 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @l4m2*

```js
f=(n=45358)=>n%63?f(n-1333)+n.toString(36)+' ':''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcH/CkAwEADgV/GPdpcoHZIaD@EJxKb5cadtKU8/33cs7xJW755Yhsdtxt/Cp/lSshpYNy21PeqR844mC1zWRIQFV1Hm6B3vQB0WKlODUmkVDnKZ6pIdLCCmHw)

#### How?

We start with **n = 45358** (**yzy** in base-36). We subtract **1333** from **n** at each iteration (**111** in base-36). We stop as soon as **n MOD 63 = 0**, because **12033** (**9a9** in base-36) is the first value for which this condition is fulfilled, and **63** is the smallest modulo with such a property.

```
Decimal | Base-36 | MOD 63
--------+---------+-------
  45358 |   yzy   |   61
  44025 |   xyx   |   51
  42692 |   wxw   |   41
  41359 |   vwv   |   31
  40026 |   uvu   |   21
  38693 |   tut   |   11
  37360 |   sts   |    1
  36027 |   rsr   |   54
  34694 |   qrq   |   44
  33361 |   pqp   |   34
  32028 |   opo   |   24
  30695 |   non   |   14
  29362 |   mnm   |    4
  28029 |   lml   |   57
  26696 |   klk   |   47
  25363 |   jkj   |   37
  24030 |   iji   |   27
  22697 |   hih   |   17
  21364 |   ghg   |    7
  20031 |   fgf   |   60
  18698 |   efe   |   50
  17365 |   ded   |   40
  16032 |   cdc   |   30
  14699 |   bcb   |   20
  13366 |   aba   |   10
  12033 |   9a9   |    0
```

Comment: How did you decide base36? and are you sure its optimal?

Comment: @LiefdeWen It's the lowest base to contain all the letters, so it's optimal.

Comment: @user202729 What do you mean? He's not OP, so he's one of those people you refer to?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Ok, that's fair. I can't force everyone to put answers into spoiler tag like in puzzling SE.

Comment: As an (un)interesting side-node, 1333 = 666*2+1 and this is my 666th answer on PPCG.

Comment: @Arnauld please ensure you use the value 1335 somewhere in your next answer.

Comment: `f=(n=45358)=>n%63?f(n-1333)+n.toString(36)+' ':''` 1B shorter

Comment: `mod 63` and` and 62` both work. Order matter

Answer (score 17):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 41 bytes

```c
f(i){for(i='ABA';i%29;i+=65793)puts(&i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOi2/SCPTVt3RyVHdOlPVyNI6U9vWzNTc0lizoLSkWEMtU9O69n9mXolCbmJmnoZmNRdnmoamNRdnUWpJaVGegoE1V@1/AA)

Fixed and -9 thanks to [user202729](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69850/user202729). -1 thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) and -2 thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld) too.

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOi2/SCPTVt3B0UHdWiNT29bM1NzSWNNGPSoqSt1as6C0pFhDLVPTuvZ/Zl6JQm5iZp6GZjUXZ5qGpjUXZ1FqSWlRnoKBNVftfwA "C (gcc) – Try It Online").

Comment: `(i='ABA';i<'ZZZ';i+=65793)` saves a byte.

Comment: Use `59e5` instead of `'ZZZ'` saves another byte.

Comment: You can use `i%29` for [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOi2/SCPTVt3RyVHdOlPVyNI6U9vWzNTc0lizoLSkWEMtU9O69n9mXolCbmJmnoZmNRdnmoamNRdnUWpJaVGegoE1V@1/AA)

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ØAṡ2ŒBY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDMeHOxcaHZ3kFPn/PwA)

-1 byte thanks to Dennis

```
ØAṡ2ŒBY  Main Link
ØA       Alphabet
  ṡ2     Slice into overlapping slices of length 2
    ŒB   Palindromize (bounce) each
      Y  Join by newlines
```

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
Aü«€û
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f8fCeQ6sfNa05vPv/fwA)

-1 byte thanks to Emigna
-1 byte thanks to rule change; thanks to kalsowerus for pointing that out

<sup><sub>Hehe, currently beats Pyth. \o/</sub></sup>

## Explanation

```
Aü«€û   Full Program
A       Lowercase Alphabet
 ü«     Pairwise with merge-list
   €û   For each, palindromize
```

Comment: You could do `Aü«€û»`

Comment: @Emigna O cool, thanks! :D

Comment: Nice, that's what I got too without looking.

Comment: According to the comments, a list of strings is fine as output, you can remove the join.

Answer (score 9):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>51</s> 48 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @ovs.*

```
++++++++[>+>+++>++++++++<<<-]>++>+[->+.+.-.<<.>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwqi7bTtgJQdjG9jY6MbawcSsNO2ida109PW09UDiurZxf7/DwA)

### Explanation

```
INITIALIZE TAPE:

0000:           (none)
0001: C_NEWLINE (10)
0002: V_COUNT   (25)
0003: V_ALPHA   (64)
++++++++[>+>+++>++++++++<<<-]>++>+

V_COUNT TIMES:              [-
    INCREMENT V_ALPHA         >+
    PRINT V_ALPHA             .
    PRINT V_ALPHA PLUS ONE    +.
    PRINT V_ALPHA             -.
    PRINT C_NEWLINE           <<.
END LOOP                    >]
```

Comment: @ConorO'Brien - I just noticed that my answer is pretty similar to yours. Please feel free to comment if you think it is too close and I'll remove it.

Comment: @ElPedro No, you're fine, there isn't much room for innovation in this challenge :)

Answer (score 9):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>51</s> 49 bytes

```
+++++[>+++++>+++++++++++++>++<<<-]>[>.+.-.+>.<<-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwSi7cAUhIQBIM/GxkY31i7aTk9bT1dP204PxP3/HwA)

An attempt at an explanation...

```
+++++                     #Put 5 in cell 0 because that is the highest common denominator of 10, 65 and 25
[                         #Start loop
>+++++                    #Counter in cell 1 is 25 (How many lines we must print)
>+++++++++++++            #Counter in cell 2 is 65 (ASCII A)  
>++                       #Counter in cell 3 is 10 (Newline)
<<<-]                     #Decrement the outer counter until the cells have the right values (muliples of 5).
>                         #Move to the counter that says how many lines we must print.
[>.                       #Print the character in cell 2
+.                        #Add one to the character in cell 2 and print it
-.                        #Subtract one from the character in cell 2 and print it
+                         #Add one to the character in cell 2 for the next loop
>.                        #Print a new line
<<-]                      #Decrement cell 1 and run again until cell 1 is 0
```

-2 with thanks to @ovs

My first attempt at brainfuck so any hints gratefully received. If I was more experienced with it then I am sure I could shave a few more bytes off but I only got into it yesterday.

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN9pOW9tO28ZGFwRiteHADixgpxtto6etp6unbaNnBxSK/f8fAA "brainfuck – Try It Online")

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>42</s> 41 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to Halvard Hummel</sup>

```python
i=65;exec"print'%c'*3%(i,i+1,i);i+=1;"*25
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWzNQ6tSI1WamgKDOvRF01WV3LWFUjUydT21AnU9M6U9vW0FpJy8j0/38A)

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 bytes

```apl
25↑0 1 0⊖3/⍪⎕A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtE4xMH7VNNFAwVDB41DXNWP9R7yqguOP//wA)

Please note that the added `⎕←` is for TIO to output the text and is not normally required.

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
Ｅ²⁵✂αι⁺²ι‖Ｏ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUDDyFRHITgnMzlVI1FHIVNHISCntFjDCMjUBAJrrqDUtJzU5BL/stSiHKBqTev////rluUAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 ²⁵         Literal 25
Ｅ           Map over implicit range
    α       Predefined uppercase letters
   ✂ ι⁺²ι   Slice 2 characters
            Implicitly print result on separate lines
         ‖Ｏ Reflect with overlap
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 90 bytes

```
((((()()()){}){}){}()){(({})<((({}((((()()()()){}){}){}){})())[()])((()()()()()){})>[()])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XwMENEFQs7oWgkBMDQ0g00YDRCFUIKkBISA3WkMzVhMhDVFgBxat/f//v64jAA)

One reason this is shorter than the other brain-flak answer is because it uses uppercase instead of lowercase characters, which have smaller ASCII values, and are therefore easier to push.

Explanation:

```
#Push 25
((((()()()){}){}){}())

#While true
{

    #Keep track of the number on top of the stack...
    # We'll call it 'a'
    (({})

        #Push A +...
        <((({}

        # 64 (push)
        ((((()()()()){}){}){}){})
        # + 1 (push)
        ())
        # - 1 (push)
        [()])

        # Push 10
        ((()()()()()){})>

    # Now that's all pushed, we push a - 1 to decrement the loop counter
    [()])

# Endwhile
}
```

Comment: I write the first version and get no upvotes you write a golf version and get +5. ???

Answer (score 6):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>45</s> 37 bytes

```
+[[<+>>++<-]>]<<---[-----<+.+.-.<.>>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fOzraRtvOTlvbRjfWLtbGRldXN1oXBGy09bT1dPVs9OzsYv//BwA)

Prints in uppercase, separated by spaces with a trailing space.

#### How it Works:

```
+[[<+>>++<-]>] Intialises the tape with the format n^2
               1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 0 0'
<<---          Navigates to the desired section and tweaks the counter
               1 2 4 8 16 32 64 125<
[-----<+.+.-.<.>>] Prints the Terza Rima, using:
                 125 as the loop counter (decremented by 5 each loop)
                 64 as the current alphabetic character (incremented and printed each loop)
                 32 as the space character
```

Comment: This is actually really nice! Good job!

Answer (score 5):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>25</s> <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 22 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to *Jo King*

```
"!;::o1+:o$oao:'Y')0.A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0nR2soq31DbKl8lPzHfSj1SXdNAz/H/fwA)

Comment: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X8nKKt9Q2ypfJT8x30o9Ul3T3trAQM/x/38A) by removing a quote

Comment: [Another byte](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0nR2soq31DbKl8lPzHfSj1SXdNAz/H/fwA "><> – Try It Online")

Comment: @JoKing: Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

## R, <s>51</s> 47 bytes

```
L=LETTERS;cat(sprintf("%s%s%1$s",L[-26],L[-1]))
```

Output:

```
> L=LETTERS;cat(sprintf("%s%s%1$s",L[-26],L[-1]))
ABA BCB CDC DED EFE FGF GHG HIH IJI JKJ KLK LML MNM NON OPO PQP QRQ RSR STS TUT UVU VWV WXW XYX YZY
```

Comment: The naive way without fancy `sprintf` is [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPwdDKyFQzObFEw8c1JMQ1KDg6WSNTJ1PbUCdTM1ZHiUtJpzi1wFZJSfP/fwA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @Giuseppe that would be because i didn't use `sprintf` correctly :)

Comment: OK, but I found a [40 byter](https://tio.run/##K/r/38fWxzUkxDUo2Do5sUSjILG4JNVAo8JG1yda18gsVgdIGcbqVGhq/v8PAA "R – Try It Online") :)

Comment: @Giuseppe ouch :)

Comment: another [40 byter][https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCMzryQkP7QkzUKjKCkzL0WjwkbXzNTKwlKnQttQp0LH0EBTU/P/fwA] based on converting ASCII codes, in case

Comment: @Giuseppe you probably should post it as a concurrent answer! NofP: you too!

Comment: @NofP not sure if you got notified, so I'm tagging you in this; and notifying plannapus that I've posted my solution as well.

Answer (score 5):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), <s>27</s> <s>23</s> 21 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to [James Holderness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62101/james-holderness)

```
j'@1+3k:,1+,,a,'Y/!1+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/P0vdwVDbONtKx1BbRydRRz1SX9FQ@/9/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/java8-2100321.html), <s>132</s> <s>85</s> <s>62</s> 60 Bytes

- 47 bytes thanks to Neil
- 26 bytes thanks to Oliver
- 3 bytes and much better formatting thanks to Kevin
- Error fixed by Oliver

## Golfed

```
a->{for(char i=64;++i<90;)System.out.println(""+i+++i--+i);}
```

## Ungolfed

```
public class TerzaRima {
    interface A{
        void a(String a);
    }
    static A a = a -> {
        for (char i = 64; ++i < 90; ) System.out.println("" + i++ + i-- + i);
    };
    public static void main(String[] args){
        a.a(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Printing a char array would probably be a lot shorter.

Comment: Thanks @Neil, didn't even think about that

Comment: Can you make `i` a `char` too?

Comment: `a->{for(char c=64;++c<90;)System.out.println(""+c++ +c--+c);}` (62 bytes)

Comment: Currently this is a snippet instead of a function or program, so you'll have to add the `v->{...}` as mentioned above by @OlivierGrégoire. ([In case you don't know how Java 8 lambdas work, I made an explanation once before.](https://tinyurl.com/yb4at8av)) Also, you can remove the brackets of the loop like Olivier did, and as additional golf you can change the print to `System.out.print(" "+i+++i--+i);` (a space instead of a new-line, and you don't need the space at `c+++c--+c`). [Try it here.](https://tinyurl.com/y89gq7mf)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen sorry, I made this without testing, hence the extraneous space I thought was mandatory. And indeed a lambda is required instead of a pure snippet. However no leading whitespace is allowed so I would reuse the `println` instead of `print` with a leading whitespace.

Comment: Thanks @KevinCruijssen for the tips as well as the java lambdas document. That was a very easy to follow guide to implement some simple lambdas. I have updated accordingly!

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper only **trailing** spaces/lines are allowed, not **leading** spaces. The fix is to use `println`: [`v->{for(char i=64;++i<90;)System.out.println(""+i+++i--+i);}`](https://tio.run/##LY6xDoIwEIZ3nuLC1KYpcTAmpuLO4ETiYhxqoXpYCqGFxBCevRZlucv9l/vua@QkedfXtqneQRnpHFwk2jkBQOvrQUtVQ7GOAFOHFWhyXdtERcyWJBbnpUcFBSDkYeLnWXcDUS85AOaHvWAMT8edoOXH@brNutFn/RDZxpI0ZcjinnOGVCxBrLh@fJiI26i/n200IqWPV8/bXdK/DWaa2NGYTWQJXw)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks for catching that and the quick fix!

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `j`, 3 bytes

```
nzʁ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJqIiwiIiwibnrKgSIsIiIsIiJd)

```
n   # Lowercase alphabet
 z  # Overlapping pairs of elements
  ʁ # Mirror each
    # (j flag joins list of lines by newlines)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
ẊS:`e…"AZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@GurmCrhNRHDcuUHKP@/wcA)

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 41 bytes

```
-[[<+>--->++>>>+<<<<]>+]>>>[<<.+.-.+>.>-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fNzraRttOV1fXTlvbzs5O2wYIYu20Y4HsaBsbPW09XT1tOz073dj//wE)

Comment: +1 I follow most of it but it starts with -[ Does that mean you are setting cell 0 to -1 before you start the loop? Any chance of an explanation for a brainfuck newbie if you have time? Btw, thanks for the -2 on my effort.

Comment: @ElPedro this depends on the brainfuck interpreter, the interpreter at tio.run stores unsigned 8-bit numbers in each cell, so the first cell gets 255 before the loop.

Comment: @ElPedro the initialization segment is actually generated by [BF-Crunch](https://github.com/primo-ppcg/BF-Crunch).

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
jC[GtGG
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jC%5BGtGG&debug=0)**

<sub><s>Hehe, currently beats Jelly. \o/</s></sub>

Easily translates to the follwong 05ab1e program:

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
AA¦A)ø»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f0fHQMkfNwzsO7f7/HwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 28 bytes

```hs
[[x,succ x,x]|x<-['A'..'Y']]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfYxvzPzq6Qqe4NDlZoUKnIramwkY3Wt1RXU9PPVI9NvZ/bmJmnoKtQkFpSXBJkYKKQmleTmZearFCzv9/yWk5ienF/3WTCwoA)

`succ` is such an unfortunate naming choice...

### Explanation

```hs
[[x,succ x,x]|x<-['A'..'Y']]

[            |x<-          ]  -- for x in...
                 ['A'..'Y']   -- the alphabet sans Z
 [x,succ x,x]                 -- construct a string of x, the successor of x and x
```

Comment: I do not feel like it is completely fair to return a list of strings instead of separating them with space or newline as required.

Comment: @user28667 It's usually allowed in challenges (it probably should be on the Default IO post, if it's not already). The OP is yet to respond in this challenge specifically. This is, however, no reason to downvote.

Comment: @totallyhuman At the moment the challenge explicitly specifies that either spaces or newlines should be used to separate the output, thus this answer is currently invalid. So strictly according to the site rules it should be deleted, or just fixed by prepending a `unlines` or `unwords`.

Comment: @Laikoni I seem to have ninja'd you. The challenge doesn't explicitly deny a list of lines as output. (Plus, that would invalidate a fair amount of answers.) Either way, the answer is now *not* invalid.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 15 bytes

```
u:2$~&3\65+i.26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I1@h1MpIpU7NOMbMVDtTz8js/38A)

Comment: This is a tricky way to make a palindrome!

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```powershell
65..89|%{-join[char[]]($_,++$_,--$_)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/38xUT8/Cska1WjcrPzMvOjkjsSg6NlZDJV5HWxtI6OqqxGvW/v8PAA)

Loops from `65` to `89`. Each iteration, we're constructing an integer array of (the current, one more, and the current) of the current digit, using pre-increment and pre-decrement. That's then re-cast as a `char`-array, and `-join`ed together into a single string. Each string is left on the pipeline and an implicit `Write-Output` at program completion gives us a newline between each element for free.

---

Alternatively, same byte count

```powershell
65..89|%{-join[char[]]($_,($_+1),$_)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/38xUT8/Cska1WjcrPzMvOjkjsSg6NlZDJV4HiLUNNXVU4jVr//8HAA)

Comment: `($_,($_+1),$_)` is an alternative same-length tuple

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>34</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

Based on [totallyhuman's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman) answer. **-1** byte thanks to [H.PWiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71256/h-pwiz)

```hs
do x<-['A'..'Y'];x:succ x:x:" "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfmFdcnlpkG/M/JV@hwkY3Wt1RXU9PPVI91rrCqrg0OVmhwqrCSklB6X9uYmaegq1CQWlJcEmRAkTb/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

Comment: [save a byte with `do`](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfmFdcnlpkG/M/JV@hwkY3Wt1RXU9PPVI91rrCqrg0OVmhwqrCSklB6X9uYmaegq1CQWlJcEmRAkTb/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 180 bytes

```
(()()())(({}){})(({}){})(({}){})(({}){})(({}){}())<>(()()()()())(({}){})(({}){})(()()()()(){}){({}[()])<>(({}))(({}()))(({}[()]))({}()<(()()()()()()()()()())>)<>}<>{}{}{({}<>)<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY65asNAEIb7eQqXUmHQypcEQqD78CFbtxJSOEUgJKRIa/Tsyv6riXETwor9vpmdX8zr9/X9a/n2ef2YJk3TcXRNu426/P6hnHRczvyRu7@hIbvPmv6iQrJWYzKlqB501XAeYg8/d2VudNzbKI@cc7iePN9b2LuFbcmb/MBXZsubgjCACcOQoDAKlQpDgBTFEbsJUpzEvw5SkiZcr1SdZin7GqQsz9g3IOX7nH0L0v6wZ9@BdDge2C2QjqcjO1a06FScZhfY0abiXMwuBEjny5ndBOlSXthXIJVVyb4Gqaor9g1IdVOzb0Fq2oZ9B1LbtewWSF3fsWMni/qhn93ETjYNT8PspgCnaen9AA)

Thanks to DJ for getting this working

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>40</s> 36 bytes

```r
cat(paste0(L<-LETTERS,L[-1],L)[-26])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKMgsbgk1UDDx0bXxzUkxDUoWMcnWtcwVsdHM1rXyCxW8/9/AA)

An alternative to [plannapus' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151050/67312); this turns out to be a bit golfier; I've posted it per his request.

See also [this 40 byte answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151208/67312) by NofP which is quite nice.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 40 bytes

```r
cat(intToUtf8(rbind(x<-65:89,x+1,x,10)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCMzryQkP7QkzUKjKCkzL0WjwkbXzNTKwlKnQttQp0LH0EBTU/P/fwA)

One more alternative in R to [Plannapus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151050/67312) and [Giuseppe's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151190/72975) answers. Posted following their request. This solution uses ASCII code to UTF8 coding.

PS if TABs were allowed, one could replace the newline (ASCII code 10) with a tabulation (ASCII code 9), and the solution could shrink to 39 bytes:

`cat(intToUtf8(rbind(x<-65:89,x+1,x,9)))`

Comment: I think using `9` is perfectly fine, since it's whitespace, which is allowed by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

## Pepe, <s>59</s> 56 bytes

<sup>-3 bytes thanks to u_ndefined</sup>

```
REeEeEEeEerEeEeeeeeERrEEEEErEEEeeREEreeerEEEEEeeEreeERee
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#!bp!aa--i-cFGS2I/)

Explanation:

```
# Prepare stacks

  # prepare stack R [Z]
  REeEeEEeEe  # push Z

  # prepare stack r [A,B,A]
  rEeEeeeeeE  # push A
  RrEEEEE     # copy and increment A (getting B)
  rEEEee      # duplicate A to end

# Start loop
REE           # create label Z

  reee        # output stack r contents
  rEEEEEeeE   # increment all

  reeE        # end line

Ree           # loop while r[p] != Z
```

Comment: Replacing `rEeEeeeeEe` with `RrEEEEE` saves off 3 bytes

Comment: @u_ndefined Thanks! I made this code before flags were added to Pepe. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes

```
PZ_.BMPz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/ICpez8k3oOr///@6eQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [vJASS](https://wc3modding.info/pages/vjass-documentation/) (Warcraft 3), <s>203</s> <s>189</s> <s>182</s> <s>177</s> 156 bytes

Using `//! import zinc "<code_path>"` command to exclude `//! zinc` and `//! endzinc`.

---

```c
library q{integer w,e;string r="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",t;function onInit(){for(0<=w<25){e=w+1;t=SubString(r,w,e);BJDebugMsg(t+SubString(r,e,e+1)+t);}}}
```

---

**Readable Version:**

```c
library q{
    integer Index, Increment;
    string Alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", Letter;

    function onInit(){
        /*
        *   Index from 0 to 24
        */
        for (0 <= Index < 25){
            Increment = Index + 1;

            // Slice
            Letter = SubString(Alphabets, Index, Increment);

            // Output
            BJDebugMsg(Letter + SubString(Alphabets, Increment, Increment + 1) + Letter);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Warcraft 3]

---

**Verification purposes only:**
The in-game text screen has limited space. Using `Preload()`, we may able to see the full output.

```java
//! zinc
library q{
    integer Index, Increment;
    string Alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", Letter;

    function onInit(){
        // Create an empty text file (Preload file).
        PreloadGenClear();
        PreloadGenStart();

        /*
        *   Index from 0 to 24
        */
        for (0 <= Index < 25){
            Increment = Index + 1;

            // Slice
            Letter = SubString(Alphabets, Index, Increment);

            // Output
            Preload(Letter + SubString(Alphabets, Increment, Increment + 1) + Letter);
        }

        // Save .txt
        PreloadGenEnd("CodeGolf\\testOutput.txt");
    }
}
//! endzinc
```

[image: Preload File as an output]

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>18</strike> 16 bytes

```
2(,{.)\u:65+i.26
```

Changed `a.{~` to `u:` after Conor O'Brien's and FrownyFrog's solutions

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfZmulYKAAxP@NNHSq9TRjSq3MTLUz9YzM/mtyKekpqKfbWqkr6CjUWimkcaUmZ@QrpP8HAA)

Comment: Alternative 16 byte: `u:(i.25)+/66-#:5`

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 32 bytes

```ruby
puts (?A..?Y).map{|c|c+c.next+c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFhBw95RT88@UlMvN7Gguia5Jlk7WS8vtaJEO7n2/38A)

---

If a list of strings is valid output:

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 31 bytes

```ruby
->{(?A..?Y).map{|c|c+c.next+c}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf165aw95RT88@UlMvN7Gguia5Jlk7WS8vtaJEO7m29n@BQppecmJOzn8A)

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge, 26 bytes

```
:"A"+:,:1+,,1+:64*`#@_55+,
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=OiJBIis6LDoxKywsMSs6NjQqYCNAXzU1Kyw&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `j`, 4 bytes

```
moᵛṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJqIiwiIiwibW/htZvhuYUiLCIiLCIiLCIzLjQuMSJd)

same as vyxal 2 but the byte lost from not having vectorized mirror is saved from the one byte capital alphabet builtin

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 40 bytes

```bash
eval '<<<$[[##36]'{13366..45358..1333}\]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY3NVLLEnMU1G1sbFSio5WVjc1i1asNjY3NzPT0TEyNTS309IA849qYWIh6qDaYdgA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 24 bytes

```
ABA
;{:G`
T`_p`p`[^Y]..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy9HJkcu62so9gSskIb4goSAhOi4yVk/v/38A)

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy8HRgavaKiQhviChIEFPT4/LMSHq/38A "Retina – Try It Online") but suffers from trailing newlines...

Comment: @Neil Yeah, you don't even need the `\`...`. Getting rid of those trailing newlines is really annoying though. I'm hoping to make printing in loops a bit more flexible and convenient in Retina 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, <s>27</s> 24 bytes

```
say$\=$_++,$_.$\for A..Y
```

previous solution

```
say$_,chr 1+ord,$_ for A..Y
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIlxlYlXltbRyVeTyUmLb9IwVFPL/L//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDAE)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

**Solution:**

```
`c$010b+/:65+!25
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/PyFZxcDQIElb38rMVFvRyPT/fwA)

**Explanation:**

Might be a better way, but this is what I came up with:

```
`c$010b+/:65+!25 / the solution
             !25 / til 25 => 0..24
          65+    / add 65 -> 65..89 
       +/:       / add left to each right
   010b          / boolean array of 0 1 0
`c$              / cast to ASCII characters
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

1 byte off thanks to Luis Mendo, by using `5B` (5 in binary) to push a `[1 0 1]` pattern.

```
66:90!5B-c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38zMytJA0dRJN/n/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 73 bytes

```
+++++++++++++[>+++++>+++++<<-]>>+<<<<+++++[>++>+++++<<-]>>[>.>.+<.+<-<.>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGxlE24EpCGljoxtrZwekbGzgksgy0XZ6dnraNkCka6NnF/v/PwA)

Answer (score 1):

### T-SQL <s>189</s> 154 bytes

```
declare @ char(26)='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',@i int=1,@@ char while(@i<26)begin  set @@=substring(@,@i,1)print @@+substring(@,@i+1,1)+@@ set @i=@i+1 end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), 13 bytes

```
{B25"PpZ~}(;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P@/2snIVCmgIKquVsO69v9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/) (repl), 18 bytes

```
u:65+(,>:,])"+i.25
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeeZmuloa6jrqkUr65TZ6BgZaCr5xzk4/a/1MrMVFtDx85KJ1ZTSTtTz8j0vyZXanJGvkKauvp/AA)

Can be made into a function for +4 bytes:

```
(u:65+(,>:,])"+i.25)"_
```

Other solutions:

```
u:|:65 66 65+/i.25
```

### Explanation

```
u:65+(,>:,])"+i.25
              i.25     range [0, 25)
     (     )"+         on each number:
      ,  ,               create a list composed of the number,
       >:                the number + 1
          ]              and the number
                       this gives the 2D list [0 1 0] [1 2 1] ...
  65+                  add 65 to each element
u:                     convert to characters
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 99 bytes

```
@set s=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
:l
@echo %s:~0,2%%s:~0,1%
@set s=%s:~1%
@if not %s%==Z goto l
```

Only 10 bytes shorter than a literal...

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 42 bytes

```
{('A'..'Y').map{println("$it${it+1}$it")}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@1@WmKOQbaWhqWsXmpdZomCr8L9aQ91RXU9PPVJdUy83saC6oCgzryQnT0NJJbNEpTqzRNuwFshS0qyt/Z9WmqeQm5iZp5FYlF5speBYVJRYaRNcAtSQbqdZzaUABNkamly1/wE)

or

```
{('A'..'Y').map{println(""+it+(it+1)+it)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYsxCsMwDAD3vEJksUSooWtIAnlD6dBRS4OwowRHLRTjt7s@OLjlwmFRtH45QhiRbstTxWCGmtGtznv3cuR3PvOZRC0q9v0gNmDzTq2olPr@KOwsipy2a4Q1Jf5ND2vDtlDuoBGQulL/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```
L,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"dBREpBR2DBcEJn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HR8nRydnF1c3dw9PL28fXzz8gMCg4JDQsPCIySinFKci1wCnIyMUp2dUr7/9/AA)

Who needs all these "palindromise" functions?

2 bytes saved thanks to DLosc!

### How it works (old version)

```
L,     - Create a nilary lambda function.
  "…"  - Push the uppercase alphabet;     STACK = ['ABC…XYZ']
  d    - Duplicate;                       STACK = ['ABC…XYZ' 'ABC…XYZ']
  BR   - Reverse;                         STACK = ['ABC…XYZ' 'ZYX…CBA']
  2D   - Duplicate from below;            STACK = ['ABC…XYZ' 'ZYX…CBA' 'ABC…XYZ']
  Ep   - Dequeue each;                    STACK = ['BCD…XYZ' 'YXW…CBA' 'BCD…XYZ']
  $BR$ - Reverse the middle string;       STACK = ['BCD…XYZ' 'ABC…WXY' 'BCD…XYZ']
  Bc   - Zip;                             STACK = [['A' 'B' 'A'] … ['Y' 'Z' 'Y']]
  EJ   - Join each;                       STACK = ['ABA' … 'YZY']
  n    - Join with newlines               STACK = ['ABA…YZY']
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Shnap](https://github.com/ShnapLang/Shnap), 35 bytes

```
for c:'A'..'Z'println(""+c+(c+1)+c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87ISyz4/z8tv0gh2UrdUV1PTz1KvaAoM68kJ09DSUk7WVsjWdtQUztZ8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak classic](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>160</s> <s>150</s> 118+2=120 bytes with -A flag

```
((((((()()()){}){}){}){}){}())<>(((((()()()()())){}){}){}){({}[])<>([{}])[({}())][({}[])]({}())[((()()()()()){})]{}<>}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XwMCNEFQs7oWGQEFbOyQpMFKkBRoVNdGx4KURFfXxmpGa4B1xEZDhGMh3GgUzUBdsdW1Nna1////181RSM5JLC7OTP6v6wgA)

The separator is a newline.

-8 bytes thanks to DJ

-32 bytes thanks to DJ

Comment: The first 50 bytes are rather redundant. in general, rather than doing `(...)(({}){})` you can do `((...){})` to save 4 bytes. And of course, this can be nested several times. To push `'a'` I would do `((((((()()()){}){}){}){}){}())` instead.

Comment: You can also use https://brain-flak.github.io/integer/ to autogolf large integers for you.

Comment: And [minus 32 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XwMCNEFQs7oWGQEFbOyQpMFKkBRoVNdGx4KURFfXxmpGa4B1xEZDhGMh3GgUzUBdsdW1Nna1////181RSM5JLC7OTP6v6wgA "Brain-Flak – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>83</s> <s>82</s> <s>81</s> <s>79</s> 72 bytes

```
R	&UCASE POS(I) LEN(1) . L @I LEN(1) . R	:F(END)
	OUTPUT =L R L	:(R)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/P4hTLdTZMdhVIcA/WMNTU8HH1U/DUFNBT8FHwcETwQvitHLTcPVz0eTi9A8NCQgNUbD1UQhS8OG00gjS5AJK/P8PAA)

I think I'm finally getting the hang of `@`!

SNOBOL variables are initialized automatically to `""` which is also equivalent to `0`. So the first time the interpreter sees line `R`, the line is:

```
&UCASE POS(0) LEN(1) . L @I LEN(1) . R  :F(END)
```

which finds a `LEN`gth `1` string starting at `POS`ition 0 (the beginning of the string), assigning the matched string to `L`. Then we assign the position of *that* match to `I` using `@`, which has been incremented by `1` because of the `LEN(1) . L`. The next character is then matched and assign it to `R`, and output `L R L`. This continues until `I` is 25, since then `LEN(1) . R` fails to match, as `L` would be `Z`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>11</s> 6 bytes

Returns an array of lines.

```
;BäÈiZ
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O0LkyGla&input=LVI=)

---

### Explanation

- `;B` is the uppercase alphabet.
- `äÈ` gets each pair of consecutive characters in a string and passes them through a function.
- `iZ` prepends the current element to the first character of the current element.

---

### Alternative, 6 bytes

```
;Bã mê
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O0LjIG3q&input=LVI=)

---

#### Explanation

- `ã` splits the alphabet string into an array of consecutive character pairs.
- `m` maps over the array.
- `ê` palindromises the current element.

Comment: Array of lines is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 9 bytes

```
Z1Z25:QKh
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/z/KMMrI1CrQO@P/fwA)**

**Explanation:**

```
Z1Z          \ Make the stack [0, 1, 0]
   25:       \ 25 times do:
      Q      \    Print the stack, as indexes into the uppercase alphabet
       Kh    \    Increment all values
```

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 16 bytes

```
¬azòóˆˆ/±²±\r²òd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P92///CrGF6w7LDs8KIwogvwrHCssKxXHLCssOyZP//)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: ac61 7af2 f388 882f b1b2 b15c 72b2 f264  .az..../...\r..d
```

Recursive Regular Expressions for the win!

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 60 bytes

```
import StdEnv
t=foldr(+++)""[{c,c+one,c,' '}\\c<-['a'..'y']]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r4yrxDYtPyelSENbW1tTSSm6OlknWTs/L1UnWUddQb02JibZRjdaPVFdT0@9Uj029n9wSSJQr61Cyf9/yWk5ienF/3U9ff67VOYl5mYmAzlJAA)

If a list of `Char` (`[Char]`) is okay instead of a `String` (`{#Char}`) (they look the same when printed bare), then we can save a few bytes and use:

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 53 bytes

```
import StdEnv
t=flatlines[[c,c+one,c]\\c<-['a'..'y']]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxDoMgEADQvV/BxiD6BbrpYNLNERnOAw0JHE29NvHnPRnf8DAFIMnF/1JQGSJJzJ/yZbWwn@j/4mFPwClSOK1Fg02hYNCtK/at1aC7Tl/aOVkYahoUy411HKe081vGiyBHrNge)

If a list of `String` (`[{#Char}]`) representing the lines is acceptable, then we can save even more and use:

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 45 bytes

```
import StdEnv
t=[{#c,c+one,c}\\c<-['a'..'y']]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r4yrxDa6WjlZJ1k7Py9VJ7k2JibZRjdaPVFdT0@9Uj029n9wSSJQsa1Cyf9/yWk5ienF/3U9ff67VOYl5mYmFwMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 38 bytes

```
fori=65i<90i++print("%c%c%c"%{i i+1i})
```

Naïve solution, not very exciting, but it works.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678/z8tvyjT1sw008bSIFNbu6AoM69EQ0k1GQSVVKszFTK1DTNrNf//BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 24 bytes

```
65[ddP1+dPrPdAP90>M]dsMx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/MNDolJcBQOyWgKCDFMcDSwM43NqXYt@L/fwA)

Pretty straightforward. Start with ASCII value for `A`, duplicate it a couple of times, print it, increment it and duplicate this, print it, swap the top-of-stack, print (the unincremented number), print a line feed, keep going as long as we haven't made it to `Z` (90).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 55 bytes

```python
' '.join(map(lambda x:"%c"*3%(x-1,x,x-1),range(66,91)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fUJSZV6LxX11BXS8rPzNPIzexQCMnMTcpJVGhwkpJNVlJy1hVo0LXUKdCB0hq6hQl5qWnapiZ6Vgaampq/tf8DwA)

Comment: -2 : `' '.join(map(lambda x:"%c"*3%(x,x+1,x),range(65,90)))`

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 72 bytes

*-2 bytes because yay assumed values!*

*-15 bytes thanks to Francisco Hahn*

```php
<?php $x=ABA;for($i=0;$i<75;$i++){if($i%3==0){echo$x." ";}$t=$x[$i%3];$x[$i%3]=++$t;}?>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkVSpsHZ0crdPyizSsVTJtzE2BpLa2ZnVqcka@hkqmqrGmvZKSlUqFnpKCkrVKia1KRTRINNYaxrDV1lYpsa79b2/3HwA//AA)

Takes the string "ABA" through a for loop which loops through each character and increments it. Displays the current value of the string every 3 times.

Comment: `$x=ABA;for(;$i<75;$i++){echo($i%3)?"":$x." ";$t=$x[$i%3];$x[$i%3]=++$t;}` 72

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically), 34 bytes

```
FRF'-2(+345@+33-5@-33+5@-33200@1)6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5NykxOzMmp/P/fLchNXddIQ9vYxNRB29hY19RB19hYG0waGRg4GGqa/f8PAA)

It was hard... At least it's doable. (without too much hardcoding)

Other Rubik's algorithm may lead to shorter sequence.

Some alternatives I tried (which is, unfortunately, longer):

35 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5NykxOzMmp/P/fx8jFx0jXVNtAQ9vE2MjQQdtI19BB10gbSJgYGxo6GGia/f8PAA)

36 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5NykxOzMmp/P/fKUjdSV3XyFBD28TYyMBB28BA18hB18BAG0gaGxsZOhhqmv3/DwA)

---

Explanation:

```
FRF'      Rubik's cube algorithm. This algorithm has the property of make face
          value 1 equal to 10. (character of code of `\n`)
-2        Subtract face value 2 (which is 25) from the notepad.
(    )6   While notepad is nonzero:
+345        Add 90 to notepad.
@           Print notepad value.
+33-5       Add 1 to notepad.
@           Print notepad value.
-33+5       Subtract 1 from notepad.
@           Print notepad value.
-33200      Subtract 89 from notepad.
@1          Print face value 1 (which is 10, '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Premier](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Premier), 18 bytes

```
:| s |ns:'Z~*AUc
A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyhKzc1MLfr/36pGoVihJq/YSj2qTssxNJnL8f9/AA)

### Explanation

The second line just defines the data for the program. So, starting wtih `A` on the stack...

```
:| s |ns:'Z~*AUc
:|   |n            print the following format:
  .                   TOS
   s                  TOS + 1
    .                 TOS
                   this prints out ABA, for example
       s:'Z~*      If the next char is not 'Z'
             A        append it to the data
              Uc   print a newline
```

This repeats until the next character is `Z`, at which point there is no data left, and the program terminates.

Answer (score 1):

## vim, <s>48</s> 28 keystrokes

```
:h<_EnterjjYZZPqqy2llpi ESCl@qq@qD
```

My first attempt at golfing in vim

### Explanation

```
:h<_EnterjjYZZP                    Insert the alphabet by copying it from the help manual
qq                                  Define a macro `q`:
 y2l                                 Copy the first two characters (relative to the cursor)
 lp                                  Paste after the copied characters (ABCDE -> ABABCDE)
 i Esc                             Insert a space (ABABCDE -> ABA BCDE)
 l@q                                 Run the macro again with the cursor after the space
q@q                                 End the macro defenition and run it
D                                   Remove the last Z
```

Answer (score 1):

## Go, 56 Bytes

```
func n(){for i:=65;i<90;i++{Printf("%c%c%c\n",i,i+1,i)}}
```

**Ungolfed and readable:**

```
func n() {
    for i := 65; i < 90; i++ {
        Printf("%c%c%c\n", i, i + 1, i)
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8//X5CYnJ2YnqqQm5iZx8WVmVuQX1SioKeglJZbosTFlVaalwyW0tBUqObiBFJctf/BgkBmdVp@kUKmla2ZqXWmjaWBdaa2dnVAUWZeSZqGkmoyCMbkKelk6mRqG@pkatbW/v8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Go, <s>60</s> 56 bytes

```
func t(){for i:=65;i<90;i++{Printf("%c%c%c\n",i,i+1,i)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8//X5CYnJ2YnqqQm5iZx8WVmVuQX1SioKeglJZbosTFlVaalwyW0tBUqObiLNHQ5Kr9DxYEMqvT8osUMq1szUytM20sDawztbWrA4oy80rSNJRUk0EwJk9JJ1MnU9tQJ1Oztvb/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download/), 15 bytes

**Solution:**

```
+-1 1 -1_\:.Q.A
```

**Explanation:**

Take A..Z, drop the last/first/last elements and then transpose:

```
+-1 1 -1_\:.Q.A / the solution
           .Q.A / "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        _\:     / drop (_) each-left from the right argument
 -1 1 -1        / the list (-1;1;-1)
+               / flip
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 17 bytes

```
90,65>''+{.).(n}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/39JAx8zUTl1du1pPU08jr1b1/38A)

## Explanation

```
90,65>            # Yield the uppercase alphabet
      ''+         # Convert to a string
         {     }% # For every codepoint in the string:
          .)      # Push the codepoint incremented
            .(    # Push the codepoint decremented
              n   # Push a newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 60 bytes

```
8a8m2x1v2d3m7s2x2v1x1f1v1a1o1a1o1s1o2x1v0m9a1a1o1v3x2v1l0x1f
```

**Explanation** (with `0x` commands removed)

```
8a8m2x1v                               # Set variable 1 equal to 64 ("@")
2d3m7s2x2v                             # Set variable 2 equal to 89 ("Y")
1x1f                                   # Function 1
    1v                                 # Load variable 1 into the register
      1a1o1a1o1s1o                     # Output the next line of the rhyme scheme
                  2x1v                 # Store the value of the register in variable 1
                      0m9a1a1o         # Output a newline
                              1v       # Load variable 1 into the register
                                3x2v1l # Jump back to the start of the function
                                       # if the value in the register is less than variable 2
1f                                     # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>49</s> 47 bytes

An obvious golf saved 2 bytes:

```
' '.join('%c'*3%(x,x+1,x)for x in range(65,90))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fUJSZV6LxX11BXS8rPzNPQ101WV3LWFWjQqdC21CnQjMtv0ihQiEzT6EoMS89VcPMVMfSQFPzv@Z/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), <sup><s>55 53</s></sup> 46 bytes

```forth
: f 90 65 do i i 1+ i emit emit emit cr loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKVgaKJiZKqTkK2QCoaE2kEjNzSxBIpKLFHLy8wsUrP@n/QcA)

-6 bytes from bubbler.

a simple loop.

Comment: [Looping through A to Y directly](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKVgaKJiZKqTkK2QCoaE2kEjNzSxBIpKLFHLy8wsUrP@n/QcA) seems to be shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 674 bytes

```
{iiiiii}iiiiicicdc{ddddd}dddddc{iiiii}iiiiiicicdc{ddddd}ddddddc{iiiiii}dddcicdc{dddddd}iiic{iiiiii}ddcicdc{dddddd}iic{iiiiii}dcicdc{dddddd}ic{iiiiii}cicdc{dddddd}c{iiiiii}icicdc{dddddd}dc{iiiiii}iicicdc{dddddd}ddc{iiiiii}iiicicdc{dddddd}dddc{iiiiii}iiiicicdc{dddddd}ddddc{iiiiii}iiiiicicdc{dddddd}dddddc{iiiiii}iiiiiicicdc{dddddd}ddddddc{{i}ddd}dddcicdc{{d}iii}iiic{{i}ddd}ddcicdc{{d}iii}iic{{i}ddd}dcicdc{{d}iii}ic{{i}ddd}cicdc{{d}iii}c{{i}ddd}icicdc{{d}iii}dc{{i}ddd}iicicdc{{d}iii}ddc{{i}ddd}iiicicdc{{d}iii}dddc{{i}ddd}iiiicicdc{{d}iii}ddddc{{i}ddd}iiiiicicdc{{d}iii}dddddc{{i}ddd}iiiiiicicdc{{d}iii}ddddddc{{i}dd}dddcicdc{{d}ii}iiic{{i}dd}ddcicdc{{d}ii}iic{{i}dd}dcicdc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdBBDsMwCATAF/VRkWlVzj0iv92piQLsEh8seQcLaeV9yEd/39dapn6m30OHDJN9pt/Dina@XfezqOwPxYhSECKHOFKFOHcrQRUmsIaonckfBv5P8zayEfM2rkbCiFIQIoc4UoU4dytBFSawhqidyR8G7gkqpPQxGSL3eK0T)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╢#^↔2f
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b6235e1d3266&i=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 12 bytes

```
kA:2l$Zƛfṅ;Ṫ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=kA%3A2l%24Z%C6%9Bf%E1%B9%85%3B%E1%B9%AA&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Nice effort by @Ausername, +1 to them. I tried a different approach:

```
ka          # uppercase alphabet
:           # dup
2l          # pairwise
$           # swap
Z           # zip
ƛ           # map
 f          # flatten
 ṅ          # join
;           # close map
Ṫ           # slice without tail
```

Although not necessary, for beautification, I added the `j` flag.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 46 bytes

### Multiple lines

```
=CONCAT(CHAR(ROW(65:89)*{1,1,1,0}+{0,1,0,10}))
```

### One line

```
=CONCAT(CHAR(ROW(65:89)*{1,1,1,0}+{0,1,0,32}))
```

### 25 by 3 array of cells, 25 bytes

```
=CHAR(ROW(65:89)+{0,1,0})
```

*I don't think this follows the spirit of the challenge but it is
shorter.*

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 21 bytes

```
≡&p↘¯1⍉⍜⊙⊡↻.1↯3+@A⇡26
```

[Pad](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__4omhJnDihpjCrzHijYnijZziipniiqHihrsuMeKGrzMrQEHih6EyNgo=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
⊞+⇡25"ABA"
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__4oqeK-KHoTI1IkFCQSIK)

-2 bytes thanks to Lynn!

Comment: `⊞+⇡25"ABA"` seems to work.

Comment: @Lynn Nice, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, 7 bytes

```
BWR_MPz
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSbo5S7IKlpSVpuhbLncKD4n0DqiA8qOACKA0A)

#### Explanation

```lisp
BWR_MPz
      z ; Lowercase alphabet
    MP  ; Map this function to each adjacent pair of letters:
B       ;   The second letter
 WR     ;   Wrapped in two copies of
   _    ;   The first letter
        ; Autoprint the resulting list one element per line (-l flag)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
ZZ«Z⁰Ij
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=WlolQUJaJXUyMDcwSWo_,v=0.12)

Answer (score 0):

## [Standard ML (MLton)](http://www.mlton.org/), 62 bytes

```ml
fun$90=""| $n=implode(map chr[n,n+1,n,32])^ $(n+1);print($65);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87N0c3NKcnP@/8/rTRPxdLAVkmpRkElzzYztyAnPyVVIzexQCE5oyg6TydP21AnT8fYKFYzTkFFA8jTtC4oyswr0VAxM9W0/v8fAA)

#### Ungolfed:

```ml
fun f 90 = ""
  | f  n = implode(map chr[n,n+1,n,32]) ^ f(n+1);

print(f 65);
```

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 40 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs to the vbe immediate window.

```vb
For i=65To 89:a=Chr(i):?a;Chr(i+1)a:Next
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Acc!!](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 66 bytes

```
Count i while i-25 {
	i+65
	Write _
	Write _+1
	Write _
	Write 0
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/985vzSvRCFToTwjMydVIVPXyFShmoszU9vMlIszvCizJFUhHs7QNsQQM@Cq/f8fAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex), 50 bytes

```
>Z//>(.)(.)/$1$2$1 >$2/>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Outputs in the form

```
ABA BCB CDC...
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otSk1Prfj/3y5KX99OQ08TiPRVDFWMVAwV7FSM9O0cnZxdXN3cPTy9vH18/fwDAoOCQ0LDwiMio/7/BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), 64 bytes

```
0ForI=65To89:A$=Left$(Chr$(I),1):?A$;Left$(Chr$(I+1),1);A$:NextI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fwC2/yNPWzDQk38LSylHF1ic1rURFwzmjSEXDU1PHUNPK3lHFGllQ2xAkbO2oYuWXWlHi@f8/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [MY-BASIC](https://github.com/paladin-t/my_basic), 48 bytes

```vb
For I=65 To 89
A=Chr(I)
Print A+Chr(I+1)+A;
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y63UTUoszkz@/98tv0jB09bMVCEkX8HCksvR1jmjSMNTkyugKDOvRMFRG8zVNtTUdrTm8kutKPn/HwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Visual Basic .NET (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/visualbasic/), 105 bytes

```vb
Module M
Sub Main
Dim I,S
For I=65 To 89
S=Chr(I)
Console.WriteLine(S+Chr(I+1)+S)
Next
End Sub
End Module
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY09C8IwFAD39yve2BAjOCg6dGoVAsYlgnNqHxhI8yAf4r@PUqcbDu7ePlcX1OSyf6pIRS0cuTXDcw2EBmyd0DgfYfQL6o2FCyfU/WGPd8bjCWw/vFKnBQwcMwfaPpIvdPWROitXJXdCWgE3@hQ4xxl/xZX/RWtf)

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 45 bytes

```vb
For I=65To 89
?Chr$(I)+Chr$(I+1)+Chr$(I)
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3y2/SMHT1sw0JF/BwpLL3jmjSEXDU1MbQmsbwliaXH6pFSX//wMA)

Answer (score 0):

## Vim, 29 keypresses

```
:h<_<CR>jjY<C-^>PVUqqy2llpi<CR><Esc>q25@qdj
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 79 Bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MU0jRUcmyNTDWrM0EsOwPN6tTkjHyF5IwiIFfbzFRTD8Y0QTCBokpcSnogHbqGmta1tf/TNDSt/wMA)

**Code (recursive function)**

```
function f($l=25){if($l>0){echo chr($l+65).chr($l+64).chr($l+65)."
".f($l-1);}}
```

**Explanation**

```
function f($l=25){         #Running the function 25 times                  
    if($l>0){               
        echo chr($l+65)    #start getting Z
            .chr($l+64)    # Y in the middle
            .chr($l+65)."  # with chr is still less bytes than str_pad
            ".f($l-1);     #call the function with $l-1
                           #in that call we get the line with YXY
                           #the result works because its writen in the
                           #inverted order of the stack :D
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Small Basic](http://www.smallbasic.com), 92 bytes

A Script that takes no input and outputs to the `TextWindow` Object

```
For I=65To 89
c=Text.GetCharacter(i)
TextWindow.WriteLine(c+Text.GetCharacter(i+1)+c)
EndFor
```

[Try it at SmallBasic.com!](http://www.smallbasic.com/program?DQN006) *Requires IE/Silverlight*

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 37 bytes

```php
for($i=A;$i<Z;){echo$j=$i++,"$i$j
";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFQybR2tVTJtoqw1q1OTM/JVsmxVMrW1dZRUMlWyuJSsa///BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 65 bytes

```
X's65
while X-90
cast X into C
let X be+1
cast X into N
say C+N+C
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 60 bytes

```python
for a in"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy":print(a+chr(ord(a)+1)+a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHJEYAgDADAVhheMLwcf3YTQQSPBCMqVB93S6@JcBSJxApURg2zD0tcU97240QqF9/1eb/W9VQ4YzXgfGJDHAxYN1gHVuQH)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 18 bytes

```
₄‹ʁ(⟨n|n›|n⟩kAİṅ,)
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCLigoTigLnKgSjin6hufG7igLp8buKfqWtBxLDhuYUsKSIsIiIsIiJd)

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5.9, 70 bytes

```swift
let f={$0%63>0 ?f($0-1333)+String($0,radix:36)+" ":""}
print(f(45358))
```

A direct Swift port of [@Arnauld's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld) [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151025/118665).